# Origem da orientação a objetos

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, paradigma-de-programação

Já trabalho faz 4 anos com orientação a objetos mas até hoje não me perguntei a origem desse paradigma. O que estou querendo entender, basicamente, é quais foram as motivações para a criação desse paradigma, ou seja, o que se pretendia alcançar com ele.

Pesquisando um pouco li que Alan Kay pensou no paradigma fazendo uma analogia com biologia:

> Ele lançou o postulado de que o computador ideal deveria funcionar como um organismo vivo, isto é, cada “célula” comportar-se-ia relacionando-se com outras células a fim de alcançar um objetivo, entretanto, funcionando de forma autônoma. As células poderiam também reagrupar-se para resolver outros problemas ou desempenhar outras funções, trocando mensagens “químicas” entre elas.

Por outro lado, sempre os livros falam que a ideia da orientação a objetos é fazer a programação se parecer mais com a forma de pensar no mundo real (o que eu discordo um pouco, porque construímos abstrações e não cópias fidedignas do que temos no mundo real). Outros falam que a orientação a objetos foi criada para permitir reúso de código e modularidade.

Isso tudo faz com que a origem da orientação fique meio nebulosa. Qual é realmente a origem da orientação a objetos? Quais foram as motivações para o paradigma ser criado e de que forma o paradigma soluciona os problemas que o motivaram?

Ao perguntar qual a origem da orientação a objetos e quais foram as motivações estou perguntando explicitamente dos fatos históricos associados a orientação a objetos e não das motivações pessoais dos desenvolvedores para usar o paradigma.

Comment: Costumo ressaltar sempre a maior expressividade, obtida de forma natural, que esse paradigma acrescenta ao código. Não sei se colocaria isso como motivação, acho que mais como um reflexo.

Comment: Eu gostei da sua pergunta, mas minha bola de cristal diz que ela pode receber votos de fechamento como "ampla demais" ou "principalmente baseada em opiniões". Não vou votar para fechar, mas se você puder se adiantar com algum tipo de edição para evitar possíveis votos de fechamento, seria ótimo.

Comment: É @VictorStafusa, eu imaginei isso mesmo na hora que escrevi. Você tem alguma sugestão de como a pergunta pode ser melhorada?

Comment: Acho que só deixar claro que as perguntas "Qual é a origem?" e "Quais foram as motivações?" são factuais e não opinativas, independendo da opinião de quem quer que se seja (mesmo que seja o Alan Kay), além de serem objetivas (apenas é sufiente responder os "quais" e pronto), e portanto não convidam a debates.

Comment: Obrigado @VictorStafusa, adicionei um pequeno paragrafo deixando isso mais claro.

Answer (score 6):

Conforme comentários acima, quando se trata de “Qual origem?”, “Quem inventou?”, “De onde veio?”, sempre há controvérsias e discussões acaloradas.

Dependendo do ponto de vista, a origem da **“orientação a objetos”** pode ser bastante discutida. Esta resposta é baseada nas colocações da pergunta que pede um enfoque nos fatos históricos, resolução e abstração de um determinado problema, e ainda os benefícios deste paradigma na programação.

*Alan Kay* (um dos criadores da linguagem orientada a objetos *Smalltalk*) criou o *Smalltalk* fazendo uma analogia com biologia:

> “Pensei em objetos sendo como células biológicas e / ou em
>   computadores individuais em uma rede, só é capaz de comunicar através
>   de mensagens”

Contudo, além desta abordagem, *Alan Kay* e cia também utilizou e ampliou os conceitos de **objeto** e **classe"** da linguagem de programação Simula (criada por *Kristen Nygaard* e *Ole-Johan Dahl*). É aqui onde a história começa.

Como todas as grandes evoluções, a programação orientação a objetos também teve sua “origem” relacionada a questões militares/guerras. *Kristen Nygaard* foi convocado para projetar primeiro reator nuclear do seu país (Noruega). Em 1961 começou a projetar uma linguagem de simulação (Simula), no decorrer do projeto, *Nygaard* se une ao “**programador especialista**” *Ole-Johan Dahl*. O *Simula* foi concebido para ser uma linguagem de descrição de processo, bem como linguagem de programação.

A evolução natural do paradigma veio com as necessidades. Em um dos trabalhando de simulações que lidavam com explosões de navios, *Nygaard* e *Dahl* perceberam que poderiam agrupar os navios em diferentes categorias. Cada tipo de navio teria sua própria classe e da classe geraria seus dados e comportamento único.

**Ole-Johan Dahl (Feitos/Honras):**

- Mais importante cientista da computação  da Noruega;
- Em parceria com Kristen Nygaard, introduziu ideias iniciais da programação orientada a objeto;
- Ordem Norwegian Real de St. Olav (2000) - Concedido para serviços diferenciados para a Noruega e da humanidade;

**Kristen Nygaard / Ole-Johan Dahl (Feitos/Honras):**

- ACM Turing Award (2001) - Por idéias fundamentais para o surgimento da programação orientada ao objeto, por meio do projeto das linguagens de programação Simula I e Simula 67;
- IEEE von Neumann Medal (2002) (Junto com Kristen Nygaard) - Por realizações destacadas em ciência e tecnologia relativas à computação;

> Este é apenas um ponto de vista, nem de longe tem o objetivo de
>   responder de forma precisa a origem da orientação a objetos.

**Fontes:**
http://foswiki.cs.uu.nl/foswiki/pub/IFIP21/Rome/O-JDahlTalk.pdf
http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medalha_John_von_Neumann_IEEE
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_St._Olav
http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/ALGOL#Hist.C3.B3ria
http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smalltalk#Hist.C3.B3ria
http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%AAmio_Turing
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/142327/what-did-they-call-object-oriented-programming-before-alan-kay-invented-the-term
http://www.exforsys.com/tutorials/oops-concepts/the-history-of-object-oriented-programming.html

Comment: Boa resposta. Mas há também quem argumente que bastante da inspiração da OO veio do trabalho de Minsk na década de 70 com a [Linguagem de *Frames*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_language) utilizada para representar conhecimento no campo da Inteligência Artificial. Na real é como você disse: assunto controverso porque há muitas inspirações possíveis e uma grande evolução contínua ao longo dos anos. :)

Comment: Obrigado @LuizVieira :)

Answer (score -4):

Em alguns contextos, o termo modelagem orientada ao objeto (MOO) é preferível ao termo POO. De fato, o paradigma "orientado ao objeto" tem origem nos estudos da cognição e influenciou a inteligência artificial e a linguística, dada a relevância para a abstração de conceitos do mundo real. A MOO é considerada a melhor estratégia para diminuir o "gap semântico" (o hiato entre o mundo real e a representação dele), e facilita a comunicação das partes interessadas no modelo ou software (e.g. o modelador e o usuário final) na medida em que conceitos, terminologia, símbolos, grafismo e estratégias, são, potencialmente, mais óbvios, intuitivos, naturais e exatos.[1]
https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orienta%C3%A7%C3%A3o_a_objetos