# Quais as vantagens práticas de se utilizar orientação a objetos no dia a dia de uma equipe de desenvolvimento?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, metodologia, processo

Trabalho em uma empresa que não utiliza orientação a objetos, apesar de a linguagem permitir (e incentivar).

Já estudei e estudo orientação a objetos, e faço meus projetos pessoais em OO, mas não sei exatamente que argumentos poderia ser utilizados para motivar uma empresa (que está em uma zona de conforto, do ponto de vista técnico) a considerar desenvolver novos projetos de maneira orientada a objetos.

Enfim, se eu for conversar com meu gerente, quais seriam os argumentos mais convincentes em favor da orientação a objetos?

Comment: Se a pergunta fosse ao contrário, eu responderia :) Apesar de usar OOP, se procurar pelas minhas respostas, verá que sou crítica ao paradigma. Pelo menos ao abuso dele. Este *site* construído em linguagem vendida como sendo OO mas evitam o paradigma tanto quanto dá e conseguem melhores resultados por causa disto. Tem muita gente que acha que programa OO quando não é verdade. Muitos programadores acham que o fato de usar classes está fazendo OOP, o que está longe de ser verdade. Então não deixe ele ver o que tenho a dizer :)

Comment: Só minha opinião, mas se OO não está fazendo falta até o momento, talvez o ideal seja não usá-la mesmo... Por outro lado, se você puder identificar anti-padrões nos códigos (ex.: excesso de if..else que poderia ser melhor expresso via polimorfismo, funções com nomes "estranhos" para "ajudar a lembrar" a qual tipo elas se aplicam, etc), então *esses problemas em si* devem ser usados como argumento para mudança. A propósito, eu sinto muito mais falta de programação funcional quando a mesma não está disponível do que de OOP...

Comment: @ArthurdeAndrade, só por curiosidade, qual a linguagem utilizada?

Comment: @Fernando Temos projetos em C#, Delphi e PHP. A principal e primeira ferramenta da empresa mesmo é o Delphi, agora projetos mais novos já estão sendo feitos em outras linguagens como C# e PHP.

Comment: Vendo as respostas recebidas (inclusive a minha), imagino que você deve estar pensando: "ok, e agora como é que eu explico *isso* pro meu gerente?..." :P

Comment: Pois é @mgibsonbr. Estava postando um comentário pra vc nesse momento quando me fiz essa pergunta também. Na verdade, apesar de completas, ambas as respostas não apresentam argumentos estratégicos que aportem uma mudança cultura tão grande. Acho que nesse ponto, minha infeliz resposta foi a que chegou mais perto. Afinal, todas as minhas colocações afetam do ponto de vista estratégico uma empresa.

Comment: @andradedearthur Não fale com a gerência em "Orientação a objetos" - fale dos problemas do código atual e dos benefícios de se "aprimorar a engenharia de software" da empresa. Os benefícios você encontra nas 3 respostas postadas até agora, inclusive na polêmica resposta do JoãoLuizGrigoletti que, embora incompleta, está correta. Pelo que tenho visto, preferir procedural numa linguagem que suporta muito bem os mais úteis paradigmas da OO é falta ou de conhecimento da OO (OO real e não a acadêmica de décadas atrás) ou falta de experiência com códigos procedurais nestas linguagens.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### Padronização

Assim como uma criança que está aprendendo a ler tem dificuldade de juntar as letras para formar palavras, uma mais adiantada já lê palavras inteiras mas esforça-se pra juntá-las em frases, e um leitor proficiente já "enxerga" frases inteiras, o mesmo ocorre com a programação. Se você viu um laço `for` que percorre uma lista de 1 em 1 um milhão de vezes, você não se perde na sintaxe daquela instrução específica, seu olhar já cai nos detalhes particulares. Da mesma forma, se você viu N exemplos online de uma tarefa sendo feita de uma certa forma na linguagem X, ver um código semelhante já se torna sua segunda natureza.

Se uma linguagem trabalha predominantemente com práticas de OO, adotar essas mesmas práticas no seu código torna-o mais legível do que não adotá-las. Não porque OO seja mais legível que procedural, funcional, etc, mas porque os profissionais com experiência naquela linguagem já estão condicionados a pensar daquela forma. Se um projeto está sendo feito do zero, por profissionais que não são estranhos à sintaxe e semântica OO, desenvolvê-lo da forma mais "usual" à plataforma contribui para sua manutenabilidade, sobretudo se um grupo de profissionais diferente daquele que o escreveu poderá eventualmente ser responsável por dar suporte a ele.

### Flexibilidade no *workflow*

Um programa estritamente orientado por objetos não possui um "início" nem um "fim": em vez disso, ele possui um conjunto de objetos capaz de trocar mensagens entre si. A ordem com que essas mensagens são trocadas importa, é claro, bem como é possível guardar estado até mesmo global usando objetos. Mas mudar a ordem com que determinadas subrotinas são invocadas é algo (pelo menos em teoria) mais factível em uma arquitetura OO que numa procedural - pois isso não envolve necessariamente a reestruturação de todo o código.

Explicando melhor (pois essa minha última afirmação é dúbia), num sistema onde a operação A sempre ocorre antes da B, pode-se presumir certas coisas sobre seu estado no momento em que B é executado. Se você decide passar B para antes de A, é necessário fazer uma avaliação de todo o que era pressuposto ser verdade em B e verificar o que ainda é verdade e o que deixou de ser - e portanto precisa ser adaptado.

A orientação por objetos não resolve "magicamente" esse problema, mas ela ajuda a modularizar o processo de decisão: ao estabelecer (formal ou informalmente) que o objeto X possui certas **invariantes**, e só programar assumindo tais invariantes como verdadeiras, evita-se cair no vício de escrever código que "só funciona se A, B e C já aconteceu". Em vez disso a OO te força a avaliar se o estado dos objetos envolvidos em certa computação estão aptos a realizar essa computação, *independentemente da sequência de eventos que os levou àquele estado*.

Trocando em miúdos, é mais fácil criar um script (no sentido de "roteiro") para colocar ordem num sistema que permite N ações do que dividir em N ações um sistema expresso por meio de um script...

### Níveis de abstração

Idealmente, deveríamos sempre programar no nível de abstração correto para representar o problema com o qual estamos lidando. É por isso que ninguém "programa um jogo", por exemplo: programa-se uma *engine* de jogos, e usa-se a linguagem de script dessa *engine* para criar o jogo em particular. Isso pode ser feito mesmo que não se pretenda de antemão reutilizar esse código em nenhum outro jogo.

Há quem recomende o uso de DSLs ("Linguagens Específicas para um Domínio") para se atingir esse objetivo, mas em geral isso é bem pouco prático - não é fácil aprender uma nova linguagem, ou pelo menos não é fácil "pegar o jeito" rapidamente de como fazer a ação X na nova linguagem Y. Uma linguagem mais comum acaba sendo preferível, mas não faz sentido se limitar às primitivas básicas dessa linguagem para se desenvolver nos níveis de abstração mais altos.

É nesse momento que o uso de **tipos definidos pelo usuário** se mostra interessante: o conceito de "objeto" pode não ser exatamente o mesmo conceito de "tipo", mas eles têm muito em comum (e uma "classe" pode ser usada para representar um "tipo"). Ao unir estrutura de dados e funcionalidade numa mesma unidade, e combinar as operações básicas dessa unidade para se realizar computações complexas (em oposição a fazê-lo usando as operações básicas dos seus componentes), você está raciocinando num nível mais alto, mais apropriado para o problema a ser resolvido.

Reiterando: tipos customizados não são privilégio do paradigma OO, mas são um dos benefícios de se usar esse paradigma. Se você encapsula os componentes numéricos de uma matriz ou vetor não é "para nenhum programador descuidado mexer neles por engano" - mas sim para te habilitar a expressar sua computação como uma série de operações em vetores/matrizes em vez de expressá-la como uma série de operações em escalares. Se você avaliar que seu sistema se beneficiaria de uma riqueza maior de tipos (grande "se" - eu pessoalmente sou da opinião que há muitos casos em que uma estrutura básica é mais adequada, e que o uso de classes é *overkill*), esse pode ser um argumento em favor da adoção desse recurso em particular da OO (com *ou sem* herança e polimorfismo).

### Extensibilidade

Às vezes é necessário que um sistema seja extensível, em especial quando é necessário suporte a formatos diferentes de dados e/ou interface com sistemas de terceiros. Em alguns casos isso pode ser feito de uma forma puramente funcional (i.e. um dicionário mapeando um nome à função que trata daquele nome), mas em outros pode ser necessário um conjunto de operações distintas porém relacionadas (e talvez ainda guardando estado) para realizar uma determinada tarefa.

Nesse caso o uso de uma classe abstrata/interface **especificando** o que precisa ser feito, juntamente com N classes concretas **realizando** o que foi especificado, me parece ser uma forma bastante adequada de se lidar com esse cenário. Outros paradigmas (ex.: programação em lógica) podem possuir meios também adequados, mas se suas opções forem "objetos" e "cadeias de `if`s", eu diria que você tem um bom argumento em mãos em defesa do uso de herança e polimorfismo.

Comment: Nota: eu nunca parei pra pensar com detalhes no que significa "ser orientado por objetos" vs. simplesmente "dar suporte a objetos", de modo que dei minha resposta simplesmente enumerando razões pelas quais o *estilo de codificação* OO e/ou *certas características* OO poderiam ser desejáveis dadas as circunstâncias. Mas estou aberto a críticas caso por exemplo eu tenha feito mau uso dos conceitos envolvidos.

Comment: Poxa, fantástica a explicação sobre a sequência de eventos, os estados e os pressupostos. Tá ai mais um argumento interessante: entender OO é um bom passo inicial pra depois aprender e explorar outros paradigmas, como Orientado a Serviços e Orientado a Agentes (neste último, em que as entidades nem sequer são obrigadas a responder a uma mensagem recebida - um "pressuposto" ainda fortemente existente em OO). :)

Comment: Primeiramente, gostaria de pedir desculpas pelo meu equívoco nos meus comentários. Gostaria também de parabeniza-lo por sua resposta. Simples, concisa e completa. Fui de certa forma omisso, ao não retirar do termo "código macarronico", a bem escrita, programação procedural.

Comment: @JoãoLuizGrigoletti Sem problemas! :) Eu percebi seu equívoco, na realidade meu comentário teve dois propósitos: 1) dar minha opinião na sua resposta, naturalmente; e 2) quebrar o ciclo de comentários entre você e o bigown, que não só estava se estendendo além do saudável como estava descambando pro lado pessoal... Eu concordo com muita coisa na sua resposta (por isso não dei -1) mas também discordo de muita coisa (por isso não dei +1), e pelo visto os demais também se abstiveram de votar nela. Em especial, eu concordo quando você diz que "[sua] resposta foi a que chegou mais perto"...

Comment: ...de algo de interesse do ponto de vista gerencial, embora tenha achado suas conclusões falaciosas. Explicitando: "falacioso" é diferente de "errado", uma afirmação falaciosa pode ser verdadeira ainda que os argumentos lógicos que levaram a ela sejam inválidos.

Comment: Lendo sua resposta para mim está claro que entre Delphi/C# (linguagens do AP) OO e Delphi/C# procedural, OO só possui vantagens. Qual seria a vantagem de fazer procedural em vez de OO nestas linguagens? Sua resposta é uma ode à OO mas você diz pelos comentários aqui e ali que há um outro lado e não explica que outro lado é este. Optar por procedural **em vez** de OO nestas linguagens é um sintoma do não conhecimento de OO e na prática **resulta sim** em código macarrônico. Conhecendo bem OO, eu próprio posso provar que é possível procedural sem macarrão, mas não é o que ocorre na prática.

Comment: @Caffé Nesta resposta eu só apresentei argumentos *a favor* da OO, não como uma "ode", mas sim para evidenciar onde a OO tem pontos fortes e quando esses pontos fortes são uma vantagem. Concordo que optar por A *em vez de* B no geral é ruim, não importa quais são A e B - o ideal é sempre usar a melhor ferramenta disponível (desde que a mesma esteja disponível). Quanto a esse "outro lado" que você diz que eu falei, não sei bem ao que se refere (precisaria reler meus comentários antigos), seria o fato de existirem alternativas para o OO, ou seria uma afirmação que a OO também tem pontos fracos?

Comment: @mgibsonbr A sua demonstração de vantagens da OO sobre o procedural foi tão eficaz que involuntariamente se tornou uma ode - foi o que eu quis dizer. Você demonstrou que em linguagens com amplo suporte a OO, é o caso sim de usar OO **em vez** de procedural. Quando você vê um código usando pouca orientação a objetos em Delphi e C#, este código é sim macarrônico. Na prática, na falta de usar objetos (fazendo tudo procedural) usa-se escopos amplos demais, alto acoplamento, forte dependência de uma certa sequência de passos e reutilização zero. Mas eu entendo que você é mais ponderado do que eu :)

Comment: @Caffé O problema é que há aqui uma falsa dicotomia: procedural vs. OO, e mais nada. Isso ignora todas as outras possibilidades (funcional, lógica, dataflow, etc). Mas principalmente ignora a questão imperativa vs. declarativa: eu muitas vezes me vejo não só evitando a criação/uso de classes desnecessárias, como já ocorreu (num projeto recente, inclusive) de eu escrever um código pra transformar declarativo em OO porque o sistema *exigia* OO. É difícil explicar com palavras, mas veja [esse código Python/Django](http://pastebin.com/mhB5KPTL), onde eu evitei criar 13 classes inúteis só porque...

Comment: ..."a framework exigia". Caso não entenda o código, depois posso te explicar melhor, de preferência no chat. P.S. Esse código no pastebin se auto-destruirá em 24h :P

Comment: @mgibsonbr De fato onde eu engajei foi no *procedural vs. OO* em linguagens com amplo suporte à OO, que é um debate comum nas linguagens citadas. Apesar de que outros paradigmas estão disponíveis, quando você ainda não aprendeu nem a "formar palavras", a conversa fica restrita. Vou olhar o código, obrigado.

Answer (score 17):

Eu começo com a seguinte definição de Paradigma, extraída da [Wikipedia](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradigma):

> Paradigma (do latim tardio paradigma, do grego παράδειγμα, derivado de
>   παραδείκνυμι «mostrar, apresentar, confrontare») é um conceito das
>   ciências e da epistemologia (a teoria do conhecimento) que define um
>   exemplo típico ou modelo de algo. É a representação de um padrão a ser
>   seguido. É um pressuposto filosófico, matriz, ou seja, uma teoria, um
>   conhecimento que origina o estudo de um campo científico; uma
>   realização científica com métodos e valores que são concebidos como
>   modelo; uma referência inicial como base de modelo para estudos e
>   pesquisas.

Parece uma definição super complexa, mas não é. Basicamente um paradigma é uma sugestão de abordagem de algo, um modo de pensar. No nosso caso, como desenvolvedores de sistemas, é uma sugestão de abordagem para a solução de problemas por meio da automatização computacional. Eu comecei por essa definição porque é fácil esquecer que há a letra "P" ali no acrônimo "OOP" que não necessariamente signfica "Programação". Quando eu comecei a estudar o assunto, era muito mais comum se traduzir "OOP" como "Paradigma Orientado a Objetos". O que, convenhamos, faz muito mais sentido, já que programação é só o ato de construir - o planejamento da solução de problemas vai muito além disso.

*Meu principal porquê em utilizar (e indicar) um "modo de pensar orientado a objetos" advém da abordagem pregada (leia-se: "da forma de pensar").*

O paradigma estruturado é intimamente direcionado à resolução de um problema por meio da roteirização da solução. Ou seja, ao se programar, basicamente se descreve passo a passo o que precisa ser realizado para que o problema seja gradualmente solucionado. Essa abordagem é muito natural porque o computador é muito melhor do que nós humanos em executar instruções precisas muito rapidamente. E é justamente essa [a definição](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo) de algoritmo:

> Um algoritmo é uma sequência finita de instruções bem definidas e não
>   ambíguas, cada uma das quais pode ser executada mecanicamente em um
>   período de tempo finito e com uma quantidade de esforço finita.

Essa forma de pensar é suficiente para resolver problemas diversos desde que eles possam ser roteirizados, e de fato tem sido usada desde que os primeiros computadores foram criados (seja usando válvulas ou cartões perfurados). Acontece que conforme cresceu a complexidade dos problemas a serem tratados, os roteiros ficam maiores e mais difíceis de ler e entender (por nós humanos). Deve ser fácil imaginar o quão difícil é interpretar *a função* de uma sequência de instruções (operações aritiméticas em variáveis, por exemplo) no meio de um programa realmente extenso (e talvez desprovido de comentários locais). :)

Aliás, não é de se estranhar que muitas linguagens estruturadas fornecem a possibilidade de se criar funções. Talvez você não tenha pensado a respeito até então, mas o significado semântico da palavra é esse mesmo: uma função faz algo importante, ou seja, tem algum papel (uma função! hehehe) na resolução global do problema, de forma atômica e reutilizável. Essa divisão em funções permite não apenas organizar a roteirização do problema de uma forma que seja humanamente compreensível (porque para o computador é tudo saltos para endereços de memória mesmo), mas por si só já traz inúmeras vantagens como reuso de código e facilidade de manutenção (argumentos que comumente são usados pra qualificar a OOP, mas que na verdade não dependem desse paradigma).

O que a OOP é, na verdade, é uma evolução na forma de se pensar a solução de um problema. Há uma consideração em um nível um pouco mais alto do que apenas o caráter funcional da resolução de pequenos aspectos de um problema maior. Há também a representação das entidades envolvidas. Em [outra questão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/54310/origem-da-orienta%C3%A7%C3%A3o-a-objetos) sobre a origem da OOP pode-se observar que há várias inspirações para essa forma de pensar, e nota-se que a principal necessidade é relacionada a entender também:

1. Quais são as entidades envolvidas no domínio do problema
2. Quais são as relações entre essas entidades

As entidades podem ser chamadas de inúmeras formas (de classes, de frames, não importa), mas elas representam algo relevante para o problema e que agrupam (e claramente identificam) não apenas as funções (ou métodos, ou comportamentos) mas também os dados (ou atributos, ou slots) que são manipulados e necessários para que o problema seja de fato tratado.

Deve ser fácil perceber que isso é uma forma de pensar que, em seu núcleo, independe de uma linguagem de programação. Você pode construir o equivalente a classes em linguagem C usando estruturas com variáveis regulares para servirem de atributos e ponteiros de função para servirem de métodos. E novas estruturas podem ter ponteiros para estruturas existentes, como forma de simular herança. O que muitas das linguagens modernas fazem é apenas facilitar o uso desse paradigma, como já foi bem colocado por colegas em comentários. Mas mesmo que você use C++, C# ou Java, ainda há ali, nos métodos, a roteirização necessária para que a resolução das partes componentes da solução maior aconteçam. Pois, lembrando, computadores fazem isso mesmo: executa instruções muito rapidamente.

### E as vantagens?

Tendo discorrido sobre tudo isso (desculpem se ficou muito longo - tentei apenas ser didático), a principal vantagem dessa forma de pensar (ou seja, do paradigma orientado a objetos) que eu enxergo está na organização do trabalho. Como se inicia pensando nas entidades envolvidas, em seus papéis na resolução geral do problema e na relação que elas têm entre si (e que também ajudam na solução do problema), é muito mais fácil construir a solução de forma gradual. Veja, problemas complexos têm um entendimento difícil, e é comum que se perceba certas nuances ao longo do desenvolvimento. Uma organização de projeto orientada a objetos facilita a evolução do código (em certos casos, basta herdar uma classe - e aqui eu creio que seja vantajoso você ler [a respeito da discussão dos múltiplos ifs](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4731/por-que-em-algumas-situa%C3%A7%C3%B5es-ifs-s%C3%A3o-considerados-ruins/4772#4772), que também foi mencionada em comentário).

Ela também facilita a manutenção na medida em que é mais fácil para um humano lembrar das entidades envolvidas na resolução do problema do que de seus comportamentos individuais. Imagine que você precisa dar manutenção em um projeto seu mesmo, mas depois de muitos anos. Se há um problema relacionado à impressão de pedidos, deve ser mais fácil você simplesmente gastar seu tempo analisando código da classe Pedido do que procurar entender e encontrar as funções relacionadas no meio de diversos arquivos de código.

P.S.: Note como alguém que argumentasse que basta organizar as funções em arquivos intimamente relacionados estaria, de certa forma, usando esse paradigma sem saber! hehehe

Mas vale lembrar que nem tudo é vantagem. Como também foi citado em comentários, uma equipe que não estudou e não conhece o paradigma pode gastar tempo precioso aprendendo. A experiência (e o grande número de perguntas aqui no SOPT) indicam que há uma bela de uma curva de aprendizado envolvida. Além disso, para aplicações críticas em que velocidade de execução e/ou uso de memória são requisitos não funcionais importantes, o esforço computacional adicional oriundo das facilidades providas por recursos da OO (como, por exemplo, a sobrecarga de métodos e operadores, ou os construtores de cópia) podem trazer desvantagens relevantes.

Comment: Ótima resposta. Concordo: você faz um ótimo código OO e um profissional que não entende OO não poderá dar manutenção nele. Mas o inverso também é verdadeiro: você faz um código macarrônico (e tenho visto que ausência de OO em Delphi/C# é sempre macarrônico) e apenas você, com sorte, poderá dar manutenção nele. Então enquanto há o custo da curva de aprendizado de OO, do outro lado há também o custo da curva de aprendizado do próprio código. Pelo que tenho observado, o custo do segundo é bem maior, e é mais fácil encontrar por aí alguém que entenda OO do que alguém que entenda seu código ruim.

Answer (score 6):

Geralmente, se você tentar defender a orientação a objetos em uma empresa que não coloca-a como uma premissa básica, a primeira coisa que irá escutar é: -Pra que? funciona não fuinciona? Em time que tá ganhando a gente não mexe.

Na verdade, o código macarronico tem suas vantagens. É fácil de fazer, é muito rápido de desenvolver e geralmente, programas que entram em produção utilizando essa "arquitetura" rodam assustadoramente mais rápido do que seus primos almofadinhas.

Pra vc arrumar um código macarronico que vc fez é uma coisa. Outra completamente diferente é colocar esse software na mão de um novo desenvolvedor. O cara vai ficar louco. Outro problema surge quando alguem quiser melhorar esse software. Aquela velha história...meu software vende maças. Mas agora eu quero vender uva...

Elucidado o contexto vamos às minhas justificativas.

- Dependencia de Profissionais - Quem entende um código macarronico é só seu criador. Se outro profissional por as mãos, provavelmente passará meses decifrando o que o outro desenvolvedor fez. Diante disso, cria-se uma relação de dependencia entre a empresa e o desenvolvedor do sistema. Esse profissional passa a ficar mais caro a cada dia, afinal o sistema não pode parar e não é fácil achar alguém que consiga dar continuidade ao projeto. O sujeito se torna virtualmente insubstituível, o que não é bom pra empresa.
- Manutenção e Evolução - Como disse anteriormente, o software é de vender maça e não uva. Aí começam as gambiarras. Você olha o código e começa achar um monte de "flags" e um monte de "if's" do tipo: if(Uva)...em pouco tempo o software não comporta mais manutenção. Aí dão uma de louco e reescrevem todo o código, porque é rápido fazer sem padrões de projeto. O ciclo continua e o criador do software uma hora dessas tá ganhando uns mil reais a mais. E todo mundo acha que ele é o cara, pq ninguém conseguiu mexer no software. Outro fator importante é a gestão de mudanças. Como fazer gestão de mudanças em um software onde provavelmente nem o programador sabe dizer quais as ramificações daquela mudança?
- Efeitos colaterais de evolução - Já reparou que ao alterar uma funcionalidade em um software desenvolvido fora dos padrões da OOP sempre surgem erros inesperados em outras áreas do software? Claro, afinal aquele campo que vc precisou remover do CRUD afeta outras 300.000 áreas do software. Esses efeitos colaterais prejudicam diretamente o negócio da empresa, gerando prejuízos.

Sendo assim, as vantagens práticas em minha opinião são:

- Código OO é fácil de entender.
- Um projeto OO pode ser facilmente desenvolvido por uma equipe, o que não ocorre com o código macarronico.
- Com o código OO é fácil encontrar profissionais que possam dar continuidade a projetos
- Permite que os colaboradores da empresa possam tirar férias
- Garantem uma melhor manutenção e evolução do sistema, já que utilizam "pequenos blocos de funcionalidades"
- São menos sucetíveis a efeitos colaterais, já que as dependencias são mapeadas com mais clareza.

E principalmente,

- Acaba com o estrelismo dos programadores.

Comment: Curiosamente eu não consigo entender códigos "lasanhanicos" que eu vejo hoje em dia. Também não entendo códigos ilegíveis, em qualquer paradigma, principalmente feitos porque quem não entende todos os conceitos de desenvolvimento de software. O fato de usar OOP não resolve nenhum problema que você cita. Fazer certo em qualquer paradigma é que resolve. Então não vi um fundamento na sua resposta que mostre que OOP deva ser usado. Note que eu uso o paradigma quando necessário. E, procedural ou OOP, minha experiência é oposta da sua.

Comment: Concordo que não resolve. Se seu estilo é o procedural como foi o meu ha uns  anos atrás, e se vc organiza seu código tudo bem. O problema é que hoje, grande parte das linguagens são Orientada a Objetos. O que não dá é o sujeito tentar fazer uma programação quase procedural em cima de uma linguagem OO.

Comment: Em relação ao Cobol, já pegou um software desenvolvido por outra pessoa em cobol? Tive muitos problemas com isso na minha vida. Grande parte dos softwares que meu pai deixo pra eu cuidar depois que faleceu eram em cobol. Meu pai era um cara até organizado. Mas foi bem difícil entender o que ele tinha feito. Já os códigos deixados em C++ foram bem mais rápidos, graças a segmentação do código em pequenas partes. Graças a OO

Comment: Quase nenhuma linguagem é orientada a objetos. A maioria permite usar estes paradigma se você quiser. Algumas facilitam isto, outras nem tanto, e pior, algumas o fazem tão porcamente que é melhor nem usar. "Todo mundo" programa, vou chutar uns, 80% do tempo de forma procedural em linguagens que você chama de OO. Alguns até podem fazer isto um pouco menos. Mas o que fazem muito menos normalmente produzem códigos que não são entendidos por outras pessoas sem documentação muito maior que a necessária quando é mais procedural.

Comment: Como eu já disse antes, eu já peguei programas mal escritos em diversas linguagens tanto em procedural, quanto em OO. Você já andou num Trabant? Isto não quer dizer que carro é um péssimo meio de transporte. Eu conheço ótimos códigos escritos em COBOL e alguns dos códigos mais difíceis de entender que eu já vi foram em C++ usando bastante OO. Você já olhou seus códigos antigos? Os meus eram péssimos. Eu melhorei com o tempo. Melhorei mais quando aprendi outras linguagens. Eu aprendi entender onde está o problema. E não é o paradigma.

Comment: Sou obrigado a discordar de vc. A maioria das linguagens de hoje (com exceção a PHP e outras poucas) são realmente orientadas a objetos. E o problema, como você mencionou é que 80% das pessoas ainda tentam programar procedural. Aí não fica legal. Não critico a programação procedural, muito pelo contrário. Hoje, tenho desenvolvido muito mais procedural do que OO, afinal estou trabalhando com microcontroladores. Agora critico sim utilizar uma linguagem OO para se programar procedura.

Comment: O problema em minha opinião está exatamente no fato delas darem a liberdde de vc fugir dos padrões. O que não acontecia por exemplo no smalltalk

Comment: Como já te disse, não culpo o paradigma, culpo a gambiarra de se tentar seguir um paradigma em cima de outro.

Comment: Acho que você não entende bem os paradigmas e como as linguagens são constituídas. Sua informação está incorreta. Realmente orientada a objeto só tem uma linguagem e quase ninguém usa. Com características OO tem várias. Se você não olhar para o marketing e for ver a literatura sobre o assunto verá que as linguagens de sucesso são híbridas. E acho que você tem um ruído em achar que se a linguagem permite OO as pessoas deveria só usar isto. Elas dão liberdade porque isto é vantajoso. Programadores experientes não são puristas, purismo não soluciona problemas.

Comment: Embora concorde com as ideias por trás da sua resposta, estou vendo uma falsa dicotomia aqui: a programação não se divide em "macarrônico" e "orientada por objeto" - existem muitas outras formas de se programar. Mesmo restrito ao paradigma imperativo, a forma de se modularizar o sistema, as construções aceitas ou não, etc, têm um grande impacto nessas características não funcionais importantes que você cita. E quanto à "dependência de profissionais", você tem razão, esse é um tópico pra não ser subestimado. Por outro lado, exagere na dose e você cai na situação do "menor denominador comum"...

Comment: @JoãoLuizGrigoletti Você está respondendo a mim ou ao bigown? Meu último comentário não foi pra impor nada, apenas estou apontando o que eu vi. Primeiro você listou uma série de características não funcionais importantes, e eu concordei com todas elas. Depois você atribuiu as características negativas à programação procedural, e as positivas à orientada por objeto, e é nesse ponto que eu discordei. Agora, se você tem bons argumentos para dar suporte à sua afirmação que a OOP possui essas boas características *intrinsicamente*, e a procedural não, aí já é outra história...

Comment: @mgibsonbr, antes de mais nada peço desculpas, meu comentário não era pra vc. Concordo que não existem só essas duas divisões. Porém acho que em uma linguagem orientada a objetos deve-se programar orientado a objetos. Como disse acima, programo muito em C. Tenho programado muito em Verilog também e nenhuma delas é orientada a objetos. Sinceramente, esse papo de não existir linguagem orientada a objetos é ultrapassado. Paradigmas mudam. O que quis dizer com código macarronico é que no contexto atual, com as linguagens modernas e orientadas a objetos não faz sentido programar de forma procedural

Comment: ...nessas linguagens, já que elas não foram feitas pra isso. Caso queira fazer isso, utilize uma das milhares de linguagens maravilhosas que usam desse paradigma no mercado. Ou então utilize uma que permita uma flexibilidade de paradigma, como php

Comment: E sinceramente, após ler minha resposta, reparei que realmente atribuo a programação macarronica ao paradigma procedura. Falha Minha. Retrato-me publicamente em relação a isso.

Comment: @Maniero muito tempo depois, mas estou lendo vantagens de Programar OO, em um comentário você fala " _italic_Realmente orientada a objeto só tem uma linguagem e quase ninguém usa. Com características OO tem várias._italic_" Qual seria está linguagem  'realmente' OO?

Comment: @LuizAugusto Smalltalk, e mesmo esse há questionamentos, já há entendimento que ela é orientada a mensagens e não objetos :)

Answer (score 2):

Esta poderia ser uma questão mais para o [Workplace](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiTpL-kmeDnAhXSKLkGHYONBGoQFjAAegQIBxAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fworkplace.stackexchange.com%2F&usg=AOvVaw3Jk_hCSxESbhvuJpvRb3I_) do que técnica. Sempre que envolve convencer a gerência podemos nos deparar com diversos barreiras que vão além do próprio código ou sistema.

Imaginando que não teremos estas barreiras, digamos, políticas dentro da sua empresa que possam impedir isto, e que a empresa poderia permitir uma mudança mais "brusca" em um novo projeto ou projeto existente (além de OO, poderia ser uma nova linguagem, framework, etc), **que seus colegas também estão alinhados com o seu pensamento**, então podemos partir para o ponto principal desta discussão.

Tentarei argumentar de uma forma menos técnica, pois você precisa alinhar o seu discurso de acordo com o seu interlocutor. **Se argumentar de forma muito técnica, ele pode não entender**.

E, por fim, não entrarei nos méritos se é melhor ou não que abordagens procedurais muito comuns como *[Transaction Script](https://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/transactionScript.html)*.

## A dificuldade de colocá-la em prática

Por mais que o assunto de orientação à objetos esteja sempre na "boca do povo", a experiência mostra que não é simples de implementá-la na prática.

Se analisar os livros de referência do assunto, comumente irá se deparar com exemplos muito simples, ou que partem de premissas discutíveis (exemplo: usar uma entidade do banco como objeto) ou complexas (DDD em geral).

Ou seja, quando estamos pensando apenas na organização de objetos para atender um problema, tudo parece lindo: crio um objeto `Ordem`, que recebe um `Pagamento`, que pode ser feito com `Cartao`, etc.

Mas quando começamos a falar de APIs entrando com dados, salvar informações no banco, validações, transações, integrações, filas, retentativas, etc, as coisas começam a ficar bem desafiadoras e outras abordagens tornam-se mais sedutoras. E isto que nem chegamos ainda no desafio de compor os objetos de forma correta (já chego lá).

Por isto, o ideal é começar com um problema **simples** e **isolado**. Este seria o cenário ideal para propor isto ao seu chefe. De preferência, que possa ser encaixado em um novo sistema apartado dos demais. É inevitável que existirá uma curva enorme de aprendizado se você ainda não trabalhou profissionalmente com orientação à objetos, então este seria um bom espaço para errar e refazer algumas coisas sem afetar o que já existe.

## Mas por quê OOP?

Alguém irá perguntar.

Aqui será inevitável fazer a comparação do modelo que funciona (ou "funciona") com a sua proposta de objetos.

O argumento mais comum aqui é "bater" no padrão atual: é confuso, desorganizado, sem padrão, regras espalhadas, etc. Dependendo de como o padrão atual foi implementado, isto pode ajudar na discussão, mas não pode ser necessariamente uma verdade **para o padrão**. Talvez o código confuso no padrão atual só esteja lá porque as pessoas que participaram do desenvolvimento não quiserem/puderam/souberam melhorar.

Então, eu tentaria trazer as vantagens evitando um pouco as comparações.

## Vantagem 1: proximidade do negócio

Uma organização em objetos permite que a conversa entre pessoas de negócio (Analistas, POs, etc) e desenvolvedores fique muito mais **transparente**. Ao falar que o `Pedido` recebe um `Pagamento`, isto de fato estará ocorrendo no código:

```
pedido.adicionarPagamento(cartao);
```

Com o esforço da equipe em tentar usar a mesma linguagem de negócio para modelar os objetos (conhecido como *ubiquitous language*).

Se seu analista/PO tiver alguma bagagem técnica, ele pode mesmo até te ajudar em algumas decisões de código se você souber direcionar ele no entendimento do mesmo.

Em outras soluções você verá algo bem diferente: talvez um `DTO`, classes de service, classes de validação, um repositório, *mapper*, etc. Algo mais distante da "realidade" do negócio.

## Vantagem 2: O código fica mais auto-explicável

Outra vantagem que enxergo é que ele limita um pouco a "criatividade maléfica" dos desenvolvedores ao organizar a aplicação. Como o holofote da aplicação são os objetos, você sempre terá uma boa noção de onde implementar uma nova *feature* ou fazer uma correção. Por exemplo, se tem alguma validação na parte de cartão, você procurará pelos objetos relacionados ao `Cartao`.

Isto também leva a um movimento natural de [organizar seu sistema por pacotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226282/are-there-best-practices-for-java-package-organization) de acordo com o negócio e não por *pattern*.

Porém, em outras soluções, esta regra poderá estar em alguma classe de serviço, classe de validação, em uma entidade, etc: Será que está no `CartaoService`? `RegistrarCartaoService`? `CartaoValidation`? `ProcessarPagamentoCartaoValidation`?. Enfim, você pode usar outros nomes de classe que julgue ter mais significado, mas com o crescimento do código do sistema isto tende a rapidamente tornar-se um problema sem um controle mais rígido e claro para nome de classes e organização de pacotes.

## Vantagem 3: existem abordagens simples para aplicar OOP

Não é preciso se basear em livro densos de DDD para criar uma aplicação robusta com orientação à objetos. Existem abordagens hoje, como a do [Elegant Objects](https://www.elegantobjects.org), que permitem o uso de orientação à objetos sem precisar isolar totalmente seus objetos, exigindo menos "infra" de código para salvar informações ou realizar integrações. Porém, violando alguns princípios considerados "sagrados". Também traz algumas práticas bem-vindas ao código, como evitar `null`. Mas não é uma recomendação, pois ele tem alguns pontos de vista [polêmicos](https://www.yegor256.com/2017/12/19/srp-is-hoax.html). É apenas um exemplo.

Poderia pensar em outras ainda, mas acredito que isto seja um bom começo.

## Show me the code!

Muitas vezes, é preciso literalmente desenhar para que as pessoas consigam entender sua ideia, o que está oferecendo ou dizendo. Isto é perfeitamente normal, algumas pessoas são mais visuais. No mundo da programação isto pode ser alcançado com uma implementação funcional.

Escolha alguma funcionalidade mais simples do projeto, que já exista, e faça uma implementação dela usando OOP. Isto permitirá uma [comparação](https://dzone.com/articles/following-oop-principles-hermetization-in-java) entre o modelo atual e o modelo orientado à objetos que quer propor.

## E se ele recusar?

Você pode ter os melhores argumentos do mundo e não conseguir convencer seu chefe. Ás vezes, não é o que você fala, mas como fala. Ou pode existir situações que fogem até mesmo do controle dele que impeçam isto e que ele não possa te contar.

Enfim, peça para ele explicar o motivo da recusa se possível e, dependendo da resposta dele, pergunte o que precisaria fazer para isto ser possível.