# O que é programação orientada a objetos?

Tags: java, c++, orientação-a-objetos

Eu sei que o C++ e Java são exemplos de linguagens orientadas a objetos. Eu sei que o
    std::cout << "string";
 é um objeto, mas não sei o que é programação orientada a objetos. O que seria?

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13372/6454

Comment: Duas outras respostas que dão excelentes definições de orientação a objetos: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/55508/14584 e http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/55507/14584