# O que é a Programação Orientada a Eventos?

Tags: design-pattern, paradigma-de-programação

- O que é programação orientada a eventos?
- O que Difere entre a Programação orientada a eventos e Programação orientada a objeto?
- Que linguagens podemos citar que são orientada a eventos?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

## O que é programação orientada a eventos?

É quando você escreve código para responder a eventos.

Na programação orientada a eventos, uma rotina especilizada em monitorar os eventos avisa o código especilizado em responder a um determinado evento que aquele evento que ele esperava ocorreu; e então o código recém avisado responde ao evento.

## O que difere Programação orientada a eventos e Programação orientada a objeto?

Estes não são paradigmas que podem ser comparados um com o outro. Seria como descrever as diferenças entre um corvo e uma escrivaninha :D

As repostas desta pergunta são muito assertivas quanto a descrever orientação a objetos: [Quais as vantagens práticas de se utilizar orientação a objetos no dia a dia de uma equipe de desenvolvimento?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/55493/14584).

Agora repare que você pode definir objetos, seus relacionamentos e suas responsabilidades, e depois fazer estes objetos responderem a eventos programando um código orientado a eventos.

## Que linguagens podemos citar que são orientada a eventos?

Desconheço linguagens "orientadas a eventos". A rigor você pode programar orientado a eventos em qualquer linguagem. Basta escrever um monitor de eventos que avise o código interessado nos eventos que ele está monitorando.

Há algumas linguagens que facilitam bastante a programação orientada a eventos: C#, Visual Basic, Delphi.

Há outras que não possuem nenhum facilitador especial, mas onde você pode usar design patterns como *observable* para responder a eventos - por exemplo o Java.

## Exemplo de orientação a eventos

Um uso comum da orientação a eventos é na programação de interfaces gráficas com o usuário.

Veja o C# WinForms, por exemplo.

Nele você escreve código que vai responder por exemplo a um clique do usuário em determinado botão, e você associa este código ao evento do clique no botão.

Então o framework do WinForms monitora as mensagens que o Windows envia para o seu formulário, e entre dentre estas mensagens o Windows avisa que o usuário clicou no botão; daí o framework do WinForms invoca o código que você associou ao clique do botão.

Comment: Acredito que a melhor linguagem para exemplificar POE é o Javascript não citado na resposta...

Comment: *O corvo e a escrivaninha*, dá um livro isso. Um filósofo :D

Comment: @WallaceMaxters hehehe é do livro *alice no país das maravilhas*.

Answer (score 21):

## Terminologia

Normalmente é usado o termo [programação dirigida a evento](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming).

Neste ["paradigma"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/141624/101) o fluxo de execução do código é determinado por eventos disparados, ou seja, algum estado muda ou algum comportamento acontece e por causa disto um comportamento é chamado a executar. A execução dos algoritmos é condiciona a algo ocorrido anterior.

Ela trabalha com o [princípio de Hollywood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hollywood_principle) onde você não deve chamar nada, você deve se inscrever para ser chamado.

## Usos comuns

Eventos tem seu uso mais comum em (G)UIs, mas pode ser usado em banco de dados, sistemas de arquivos, redes, sinalizações do sistema operacional, hardware específico através de [interrupções](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt), ou mesmo aplicações comerciais e científicas podem ter eventos em seus objetos.

Em muitos casos os eventos são disparados conforme acontecimentos que vão sendo verificados em um [laço](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop), em outros apenas há uma inscrição em algum lugar que deve-se chamar uma parte do código quando algo ocorrer.

## Relação com OOP

Ela pode trabalhar junto com OOP e até se beneficiar dele, mas não necessariamente precisam. Eles são paradigmas ortogonais e não possuem nenhum relação. Eventos podem ser aplicados a objetos, mas só isto. Qualquer relação é coincidência. Um não prejudica a outro, pelo contrário, justas eles são mais poderosos.

Em OOP os objetos vão se comunicando através de simples métodos, de passagem de mensagens. Em EDP está comunicação ocorrem através de notificações dos eventos.

EDP se dá bem com programação imperativa, funcional, etc.

## Linguagens dirigidas a eventos

Desconheço qualquer linguagem que tenha este foco e acho que só uma muito específica, talvez uma [DSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language) possa ser. O que existem são linguagem que usam este paradigma como complemento. C# é uma claramente que possui recursos na linguagem para tratar de eventos. VB.Net é outra.

Todas as linguagens, de uma forma ou de outra, trabalham com eventos, mesmo que não pareça. Isto não quer dizer que elas são dirigidas a eventos. Algumas usam muito esta técnica, mas não possuem nada específico na linguagem para tratar os eventos. Elas possuem um mecanismo que torna possível você criar seus eventos e manipulá-los. Isto torna a linguagem dirigida a evento? Não sei, mas acho que não, caso contrário seria raro a linguagem que não é dirigida a evento. Qualquer linguagem que tenha um mecanismo que permita tratar [funções como dados](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming)) de alguma forma pode trabalhar desta forma. E deve existir até outras formas de obter o mesmo resultado.

JavaScript é dirigida a eventos? Posso estar enganado, mas parece que não. O [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOM_events) e o próprio HTML parece que sim, mas a linguagem de programação não parece ter nada específico para tratar eventos. Tem um mecanismo genérico que serve muito bem ao propósito. Só isto.

## O paradigma é usado em toda computação

No entanto você pode criar códigos dirigidos a eventos mesmo que a linguagem não forneça recursos. A programação feita em JS é claramente toda dirigida a eventos. Você pode adotar padrões na linguagem que atendem os requisitos do paradigma.

O Windows é todo dirigido a eventos. Quem conhece a API Win32 sabe que no fundo o seu programa fica indagando o Windows se algo relevante para aquele código aconteceu.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: +1. Gostei também da explicação a respeito do Javascript. Pensei que ela seria indicada como Orientada a Eventos

Comment: Na verdade, acredito que o Javascript é uma das melhores linguagens para exemplificar POE. Pois a facilidade de se criar eventos é enorme, não ficando apenas preso nos eventos padrões do DOM como _click_, _hover_ e etc... Veja: [Creating and triggering events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events).

Comment: @KaduAmaral mas você percebe que é um recurso de biblioteca e não da linguagem em si? Até acredito estar tendo poucos votos por isto. As pessoas não entendem a separação de cada coisa.

Comment: De qual biblioteca @bigown? Ta certo que se amarra o evento a um elemento do DOM, mas o Javascript não é uma fusão de ECMAScript + DOM?

Comment: @KaduAmaral da biblioteca padrão, mas que não é a linguagem. JavaScript é EcmaScript, ponto. DOM é outra coisa independente que nem sempre está disponível ao JS.

Comment: @KaduAmaral Eventos estão sim previstos na especificação **ECMAScript** para computação no lado do cliente (**seção 4.1**, *Web Scripting*), e isso é "regulamentado" (detalhado) na especificação do **W3C** na forma do código que você referenciou. Então não se preocupe, está correto o seu entendimento de que JavaScript provê suporte específico para eventos. Se você se preocupa com jogo de palavras, use então a expressão *"JavaScript para computação **web client** oferece grande facilidade para se programar orientado a eventos."*

Comment: Princípio de Hollywood, está aí mais uma que eu não conhecia...

Answer (score -1):

Nos anos 1990 até o início dos anos 2000, tivemos uma onda positiva de valorização de linguagens orientadas a objetos e eventos. Especificamente, Delphi e Visual Basic vieram para elevar o nível da programação, deixando o programador apenas com a lógica, a matemática do desenvolvimento e a organização dos objetos inseridos.

O que acontece hoje é um movimento de volta ao passado, dando um olhar para a programação como algo muito exclusivo de quem tem habilidades de escrever códigos longos que incluam a orientação a objetos e eventos. Foi um andar para baixo (descendo o nível mesmo) e afastando o desenvolvimento de software mais democrático.

Essa publicação tem mais de 6 anos e praticamente se despediu das linguagens que usou de exemplo. :( Hoje temos que nos preocupar muito com pacotes e bibliotecas, com os testes e curva de aprendizado, para fazermos coisas que fazíamos com 1h de trabalho.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).