# O que é paradigma?

Tags: terminologia, estilo-de-codificação, engenharia-de-software, paradigma-de-programação

O que é paradigma?

Existe algum mais importante que outro?

É a mesma coisa que *design pattern* (padrão de projeto)?

É o mesmo que idioma?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

> O que é paradigma?

Segundo a [Wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradigma):

> Paradigma (do latim tardio paradigma, do grego παράδειγμα, derivado de παραδείκνυμι «mostrar, apresentar, confrontare») é um conceito das ciências e da epistemologia (a teoria do conhecimento) que define um exemplo típico ou modelo de algo. É a representação de um padrão a ser seguido. É um pressuposto filosófico, matriz, ou seja, uma teoria, um conhecimento que origina o estudo de um campo científico; uma realização científica com métodos e valores que são concebidos como modelo; uma referência inicial como base de modelo para estudos e pesquisas.

Em [verbete mais específico sobre programação](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_paradigm):

> A noção de paradigmas de programação é uma forma de classificar as linguagens de programação de acordo com o estilo de programação de computadores. Características de várias linguagens de programação determinam quais paradigmas elas pertencem; Como resultado, alguns idiomas caem em apenas em um paradigma, ao passo que outros cair em vários paradigmas. Alguns paradigmas estão preocupados principalmente com implicações para o modelo de execução da linguagem, como permitir que os efeitos secundários, ou se a sequência de operações é definido pelo modelo de execução. Outros paradigmas estão preocupados principalmente com a maneira que o código é organizado, como o agrupamento de código em unidades, juntamente com o estado que é modificado pelo código. No entanto, outros estão preocupados principalmente com o estilo de sintaxe e gramática.

Se tiver que resumir em uma frase: é apenas um estilo de como escrever um código. É o jeitão que o texto (código) ficará em linhas gerais.

Algumas pessoas preferem falar no paradigma de forma mais ampla e não só no código, aí é o estilo da solução como um todo.

Em geral existem algumas "regras" que determinam o que pode ou não ter no código indicando se ele é de um paradigma ou de outro. Algumas coisas são proibidas, algumas são obrigatórias.

Claro que a regra é livre, mas eu vejo algumas pessoas pegando um *subset* das regras do paradigma e dizer que algo foi escrito conforme aquele paradigma. Provavelmente é um equivoco. Inclusive porque alguns paradigmas são *subsets* de outros, aí você dá um nome para uma coisa quando na verdade é outra.

É comum as pessoas quererem que seu código seja do paradigma da moda, mesmo que ele nem passe perto daquilo.

> Existe algum mais importante que outro?

Não dá para afirmar isso. Existem alguns mais populares (tecnicamente ou por marketing).

Algumas pessoas consideram que [só existem três ou quatro paradigmas](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThereAreExactlyThreeParadigms). Determinam isso através de um vetor com duas características que o código pode ter.

"Mas eu vi uma lista enorme no artigo da Wikipedia". Sim, existem diversos outros secundários que podem ser combinados com esses principais. Mas não perca de vista que eles são secundários, mesmo que algum deles seja mais famoso. Fama nada tem a ver com utilização efetiva. Alguns consideram um abuso chamá-los de paradigma.

As linguagens podem executar ou avaliar, focar no mecanismo ou na consequência.

- Quando **executa** e foca no **mecanismo** tem-se o paradigma **imperativo**. É disparado o mais usado, para o bem ou para o mal seu uso é esmagador. Na prática a maioria dos programadores nunca experimentaram nada fora dele. A imensa maioria das linguagens são baseadas nele. Todas as fortemente *mainstream*.
- Quando **avalia** e foca no **mecanismo** tem-se o paradigma **funcional**. Tem um nicho expressivo que o usa, mas é só isso (pelo menos em sua forma pura, se bem que dizem que não existe nenhum linguagem viável de fato puramente funcional). É muito comum pegar partes dele para complementar o imperativo. [Lisp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_(programming_language)), [ML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ML_(programming_language)), [Haskell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskell_(programming_language)), são exemplos.
- Quando **avalia** e foca na **consequência** tem-se o paradigma **lógico**. Sua utilização é extremamente restrita e a imensa maioria dos programadores nunca viram um código nele. A ascensão da inteligência artificial poderia aumentar ligeiramente o seu uso, mas não está acontecendo. [Prolog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolog) é a linguagem mais clássica.
- Quando **executa** e foca na **consequência** tem-se o paradigma de **metas**. Na prática não é usado em lugar algum, por isso alguns o desconsideram.

[image: Paradigmas]

Outros paradigmas basicamente não podem existir sem que estes estejam na base. Por isso os demais são ortogonais e estes não o são entre eles (ainda que se possa misturar alguns elementos, mas não todo o paradigma).

Há quem diga que só há o imperativo e o declarativo. Posso aceitar essa definição.

Há um definição que a linguagem só pode ter um paradigma, o resto são *features* extras. Faz sentido. E aí é melhor definir só os principais, se tentar definir todas combinações possíveis vira uma loucura.

#### OOP

"Mas ouço tanto de orientação a objeto, ele não é importante?". Não. Ele é útil. Para alguns problemas, é uma escolha altamente desejável. Outras vezes um paradigma parecido, ou uma combinação de outros paradigmas, é mais adequado.

Mesmo em linguagens ditas puramente orientadas a objeto (estou falando de [Smalltalk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smalltalk), nem de Java, Ruby e coisas do tipo que chega ser risível usar as palavras "OO" e "pura" junto com seus nomes) no fundo o paradigma base é [imperativo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81854/101) com forte influência da orientação a objeto. É verdade que o imperativo tenta ser escondido, mas ainda está lá.

Sua importância está mais na cabeça das pessoas (ainda que a maioria nem entende o que o paradigma quer dizer e como usá-lo, até porque há controvérsias sobre o que ele é de fato) do que na capacidade de definir algo útil para o código. Ele é útil em pontos bem específicos. Correndo o risco da resposta ficar datada, ele é o Trump da programação. Todos falam dele, poucos o entendem. Muitos o apoiam, poucos precisam disto na maior parte do tempo. Ele é útil, mas não para protagonismo.

Se você for dos que consideram que os secundários nem são paradigmas, então OO não é um paradigma :P

#### Paradigmas secundários

Alguns passam raspando como paradigma. Se achar que só é paradigma se puder existir de forma independente então talvez nenhum destes sejam paradigmas de fato.

Grande parte deles referem-se à organização do código (em geral às estruturas de dados) ou a um mecanismo específico, portanto ele só pode ser aplicado em parte do código. Por isso muitas vezes se usa a expressão "orientado a".

Já falei do mais famoso.

[Meta programação](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaprogramming) é um usado em algumas linguagens e tende ser usado cada vez mais para dar flexibilidade e expressividade ao código, quando os problemas estão cada vez mais complexos e vão achando boas soluções. Uma parte disso é a [reflexão](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_programming)). A programação [genérica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_programming) é outro que é um *subset* deste. Já a [orientação à linguagem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language-oriented_programming) é provavelmente um *superset*.

Um mecanismo importante é o [evento](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming). Outro, em alguns problemas, é o [agente](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agent-oriented_programming).

Outro mecanismo bem interessante ganhando um pouco de popularidade é o [orientado a aspecto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming).

É comum existirem pontos específicos para facilitar o [paralelismo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_computing) e a [concorrência](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrent_computing).

Cada vez mais é usado o de [contrato](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract). Nem todos consideram um paradigma, mas se não for, a maioria dos secundários não é.

Algumas linguagens adotam algum mecanismo bem específico. Até o paradigma [genético](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_programming) existe.

As pessoas deveriam conhecer mais o paradigma [modular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_programming) ([mais informações](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ModularProgramming)). Em certo aspecto é um *superset* de OOP.

Enfim, só para citar alguns.

Há quem considere que [não existem paradigmas](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThereAreNoParadigms). Eu discordo.

Diagrama mostrando os principais paradigmas:

[image: Paradigmas de programação]

> É a mesma coisa que *design pattern*?

Não é a mesma coisa. Um [padrão de projeto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/96452/101) é algo mais específico, resolve algo mais contido e tem um exemplo mais concreto de como implementar uma solução para o problema. Está mais para um gabarito.

Muitas vezes um padrão de projeto é implementado na linguagem de forma transparente, ajudando atingir um objetivo de um paradigma.

Se a solução envolver um nível acima de abstração do problema provavelmente ele será chamado padrão de arquitetura.

> É o mesmo que idioma?

São técnicas mais específicas, normalmente dentro de um paradigma. É comum se aplicar apenas a uma linguagem específica. Digamos que fica em um meio termo entre o padrão de projeto e o paradigma.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Fantástica resposta. :)

Comment: Que tipo de paradigma se enquadraria o Assembly?

Comment: @DenerCarvalho boa pergunta, eu diria que é imperativo puro, mas alguém poderia me desmentir :)

Comment: @bigown "Script" pode ser considerado um paradigma de programação?

Comment: Outra boa pergunta :) Acho que não, mas poderia ser dependendo de como se analisa. Pra validar isto precisaria alguém escrever algo convincente mostrando porque é um paradigma. Estas coisas depende sempre de alguém dizer que é, com propriedade. Note que na resposta eu não falo muito em ser ou não, fala que algumas pessoas acham. Tem quem discorde. Essas coisas são complicadas.

Comment: "Pra validar isto precisaria alguém escrever algo convincente mostrando porque é um paradigma." => Do Houaiss: `Paradigma. 1. um exemplo que serve como modelo; padrão. 2. conjunto de formas vocabulares que servem de modelo para um sistema de flexão ou de derivação (p.ex.: na declinação, na conjugação etc.); padrão.` Scripts têm características fundamentais (i.e. erros somente em tempo de execução, ausência - em princípio - de compilação, etc) e condições ideais de uso (i.e. facilidade de alteração) que *arguably* tornam o conceito em uma espécie de modelo a ser seguido. Logo, um paradigma. :)

Comment: @LuizVieira concordo com tudo, só não vi algo mais formal dizendo isto. Reafirmo, não acho que você está errado, muito pelo contrário, mesmo, mas é só uma pessoa dizendo em um comentário do SOpt :P Você me convenceu, falta convencer o resto. Põe na Wikipedia e espere a lenha :) Não tem o mesmo peso de um escrutínio acadêmico, mas já é alguma coisa.

Comment: Vc tem toda a razão. E eu realmente não sou ninguém pra tentar convencer aos demais (mesmo a você). A intenção era mesmo só exercitar minha argumentação e tentar a resposta (afinal, soou um pouco como um desafio pro meu nível de nerdice... rs)

Answer (score 18):

## O que é paradigma?

Em programação, um paradígma é uma maneira de se pensar sobre problemas e desenvolver as soluções. Diz-se que uma dada linguagem de programação *suporta* um dado paradigma.

Ao resolver um problema, o programador desenvolve um modelo mental do mesmo. O conjunto de conceitos que ele usa para entender o problema e estruturar a sua solução é o que chamamos de paradigma.

Por exemplo, se ele adota o paradigma da orientação a objetos, irá pensar no problema como um conjunto de objetos que possuem estado na forma de variáveis e expõem comportamento através de métodos. No entanto, se em vez disso ele empregar o paradigma funcional, ele adotará um modelo mais matemático, modelando o problema como uma série de funções que podem ser compostas.

Da mesma forma: se ele prefere dizer para o computador exatamente o que fazer, então ele está pensando de forma imperativa. Se é melhor especificar os fatos sobre o problema a ser resolvido e deixar o computador trabalhar sem especificar como, então ele está resolvendo o problema de forma declarativa.

Esses paradigmas se concretizam na hora de codificar a solução do problema em uma linguagem de programação. É nessa hora que as diferenças entre elas se tornam mais evidentes, até mesmo entre aquelas que suportam o mesmo paradigma.

Java é um clássico exemplo de linguagem que suporta orientaçao a objetos, mas existem linguagens como Smalltalk que levam esse paradigma a lugares que Java simplesmente não pode chegar. É possível usar orientação a objetos em C, mas a grande custo: o que em Java é implícito na própria linguagem, como herança entre classes, tem que ser explicitamente codificado em C.

É possível selecionar dados em um banco de dados de forma imperativa. De fato, o banco de dados opera dessa forma. Mesmo assim é mais prático simplesmente dizer quais dados você quer usando SQL e deixar ele descobrir o que tem que fazer sozinho. De vez em quando, o software faz isso de forma ineficiente e isso vira um problema; é este o momento de pensar de forma imperativa, pois considerar *como* o banco de dados está executando a *query* permitirá descobrir a causa da ineficiência.

## Existe algum mais importante que outro?

Isoladamente, é difícil dizer de forma objetiva. Cada um deles teve um impacto único na forma de pensar dos programadores. Diz-se que não vale a pena aprender uma linguagem de programação que não muda seu jeito de pensar sobre os problemas que resolve.

Quando a pergunta é feita juntamente com uma descrição do problema a qual o paradigma será aplicado, a questão fica mais clara.

## É a mesma coisa que *design pattern*?

Padrões de design são padrões arquiteturais, modos de organizar os elementos da linguagem para gerar efeitos específicos como "garantir que apenas uma única instância de uma classe exista".

Um paradigma diferente pode tornar esses padrôes desnecessários ao oferecer maneiras alternativas de resolver o problema que não apresentam as falhas que o padrão de design tenta mitigar.

## É o mesmo que idioma?

Idiomas existem no contexto de uma linguagem de programação. Referem-se a padrões recorrentes de uso da linguagem por programadores.

Pode-se dizer que código idiomático é aquele que explora a linguagem ao máximo, e por isso é mais claro e sucinto que um suposto código não-idiomático.

Por exemplo, em Ruby, o seguinte código é idiomático:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].select &:even?
```

É equivalente a seguinte código:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].select { |n| n.even? }
```

O primeiro exemplo é geralmente preferido entre os programadores Ruby experientes por dispensar o uso das chaves e da variável `n`.

Para compreender o código não-idiomático, basta entender objetos, métodos e blocos; partes simples e básicas da linguagem Ruby. O código idiomático exige muito mais conhecimento do programador:

- Significado do operador `&` e sua relação com os blocos
- Método `to_proc`

  - Protocolo da linguagem para transformar objetos em blocos
- Símbolos

  - `Symbol#to_proc` e seu funcionamento

Dotado desse conhecimento, um programador Ruby pode descobrir que é possível combinar o operador unário `&` com um símbolo. O `&` converte usando `to_proc` e passa seu argumento como um bloco na chamada de um método, enquanto um símbolo pode ser implicitamente convertido para um bloco no padrão `:sym => proc { |x| x.sym }`. Nasce um idioma.