# É correto, seguindo a orientação a objetos, usar ponteiros para funções em C++?

Tags: c++, orientação-a-objetos, funções

Estou criando classes que representam itens em um menu, cada item executa uma ação e estou atribuindo a ação por um ponteiro de função a cada item de menu instanciado, isso é válido seguindo POO? ou existe uma maneira mais fácil e prática de fazer isso?

Segue código:

```
class MenuItem{
public:
     MenuItem(GLsizei x, GLsizei y, string texto, bool enabled = false);
     ~MenuItem();

     void display();

     void setAction(void (*action)());
     void runAction();
private:
     GLsizei x, y;
     string texto;
     bool enabled;
     void (*action)();
};

void MenuItem::setAction(void (*action)())
{
     this->action=action;
}

void MenuItem::runAction()
{
    action();
}
```

Classe que instancia MenuItem:

```
class Menu{
public:
     Menu(vector<string> itens, GLsizei width, GLsizei heigth);
     ~Menu();

     void selectNext();
     void selectPrevious();

     MenuItem* getSelectedItem() const;

     void display();
private:
     MenuItem **itens;
     int selectedItem;
     int contItens;
     GLsizei width, heigth;
};


void function(void){
     cout<<"faz alguma coisa"<<endl;
}

Menu::Menu(vector<string> itens, GLsizei width, GLsizei heigth)
     :width(width), heigth(heigth)
{
     contItens=0;
     this->itens=new MenuItem*[itens.size()];
     for(string s: itens){
         this->itens[contItens++]=new MenuItem(width/2, heigth/2-contItens*30, s);
     }
     this->itens[selectedItem=0]->setEnabled(true);

     this->itens[0]->setAction(function);//aqui eu coloco a ação no primeiro item
}
```

função que chama:

```
void keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y){
    if(key=='s')
        menu->getSelectedItem()->runAction();
    if(key=='d')
        menu->selectNext();
    if(key=='a')
        menu->selectPrevious();
    glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

Somente criei `function` para teste. Minha ideia é colocar um método em `Menu` que coloque por meio de ponteiro de função a ação referenciada a cada item. Mas o código em si funciona, apenas estou em dúvida se segue POO e se não está tão complexo?

Comment: pra menus tem o padrão iterator.. aí ele cria uma lista, ou dicionario pra organizar os itens... não sei se isso responde sua pergunta

Comment: estou criando meu próprio menu, pois estou fazendo um projeto em openGL.

Comment: Qual tipo de aplicação? por exemplo um jogo. Poderia nos mostrar um pouco do código?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Correto só pode ser dito vendo um caso concreto. Nesse aspecto a pergunta não pode ser respondida. O caso concreto não foi colocado, então mesmo que eu diga que pode fazer, se fizer errado não adianta nada o que eu disse.

Isso nada tem a ver com orientação a objeto. Mesmo que tivesse, o que importa é resolver bem o problema, não atender o que o paradigma manda.

Ponteiros para funções são perfeitamente válidos em várias situações.

Claro que em C++ é mais comum usar [*functors*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_object#In_C_and_C.2B.2B) ou mais (não tão) recentemente as [*lambdas*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function#C.2B.2B_.28since_C.2B.2B11.29). Também dá para fazer usos criativos de [*templates*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_(C%2B%2B)) ou o simples [polimorfismo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function). Se considerar que precisa dessa indireção o ideal é usar um mecanismo mais idiomático do C++ e mais moderno (porque traz vantagens).

Comment: Não importa a linguagem sempre me deparo com este problema adotar o paradigma de forma 100% . até mesmo em java acaba nos obrigando a tomar ações que fogem ao uso do OO puro. O problema que vejo é a motivação, as vezes precisamos abrir mão da elegância em busca de um melhor desempenho, outras vezes da padronização em nome da legibilidade para que não fique um código muito complexo e profundo, com muitas classes sendo chamada de formando níveis  para uma determinada tarefa. Por menos técnico que possa parecer já optei em um sistema multicamadas, pular algumas para reduzir a qtd de interações

Comment: @Delfino é mais ou menos isso mesmo. Pode ser útil: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/141624/101

Comment: li a resposta sugerida e é bastante instrutiva, e é uma leitura que merece ser refeita com mais calma.
Mas sem dúvida o C++ é a linguagem mais versátil e difícil defini la somente como OO. Eu gostaria muito de conhecer e fazer testes com Smaltalk, um dia.