# Funções lambda em C++, quando utilizar e quais as vantagens?

Tags: c++, expressões-lambda, c++11, c++14

Quando optar pelo uso de uma função lambda ou uma função normal, e qual é a vantagem de utilizar uma função lambda em comparação a uma função normal? Existe o preço de chamada de uma função em uma função lambda?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lambdas resolvem um problema de legibilidade, expressividade e praticidade. Por exemplo: antes de [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11), se você quisesse passar um predicado pra algum algoritmo da [stl](/questions/tagged/stl), existem algumas poucas opções:

- Passar uma função definida anteriormente;
- Definir um functor* e passar uma instância;
- Usar um functor existente na biblioteca padrão;
- Usar [Boost.Lambda](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/lambda.html) (biblioteca de [boost](/questions/tagged/boost)) para definir uma pseudo-lambda.

Nenhuma dessas opções são perfeitas ou suficientemente simples. Vamos usar um exemplo pra ilustrar o problema: *precisamos achar o primeiro caractere que não bate com o regex `[A-Za-z]*` em uma string*. Vamos por parte, usando as opções da lista acima (que não é exaustiva):

Passar uma função definida anteriormente:

```
#include <algorithm> // para std::find_if_not
#include <iterator> // para std::begin e std::end

bool is_alpha(char c)
{
    return (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') || (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z');
}

const char str[] = "abcd1234";
const char *it = std::find_if_not(std::begin(str), std::end(str), is_alpha);
```

Perceba a função `is_alpha` sendo passada como argumento pro algoritmo [`std::find_if_not`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find). Ter de definir uma função pra cada ponto no código que usa um algoritmo da [stl](/questions/tagged/stl) não é prático, além de tornar a legibilidade e praticidade um pouco piores, já que você terá de procurar a definição dos predicados, que podem estar longe do ponto de uso. Um dos efeitos colaterais dessa técnica é que um compilador talvez não otimize totalmente, deixando sua definição existente no binário e, tão válido quanto, não substituir a chamada pelo corpo da função, resultando em um programa mal otimizado nessa parte específica. Isso é apenas especulação, claro. Sempre meça a performance do programa antes de tirar qualquer conclusão. Os pontos sobre a legibilidade e praticidade ainda mantêm-se.

Definir um functor e passar uma instância:

```
struct IsAlpha
{
    bool operator() (char c) const
    {
        return (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') || (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z');
    }
};

const char *it = std::find_if_not(std::begin(str), std::end(str), IsAlpha{});
```

O functor pode ser definido localmente, perto do ponto de seu uso. Porém, a legibilidade não é melhorada, já que agora existe muito mais código para entender. Nesse caso, uma instância da struct `IsAlpha` é passada como predicado para o algoritmo `std::find_if_not`. O predicado funciona por chamando a sobrecarga do operador de chamada de função `operator()`, que faz o papel de checar o padrão para um dado caractere. A expressividade dessa técnica também é questionável (é preciso um maior entendimento para reconhecer um functor), mas é justificável caso o functor for simples o suficiente e é reusado várias vezes no código todo.

Usar um functor existente na biblioteca padrão:

Não existe um functor com o mesmo intuito que nosso predicado `is_alpha`, fazendo com que essa solução seja bem limitada (temos [alguns functors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional).) Mudando de exemplo, podemos usar [`std::greater<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/greater) como functor para o algoritmo `std::sort`:

```
std::vector<int> v{4, 3, 1, 5};
std::sort(begin(v), end(v), std::greater<void>());
```

Aqui, temos boa legibilidade (já que `std::greater` faz parte da biblioteca padrão, então seu comportamento é sempre o mesmo para todos), uma expressividade razoável (seria melhor ser possível usar operador embutido `operator>`) e é prático. Claro, esse é um exemplo inventado; outras situações podem requerer predicados mais elaborados, tornando essa técnica inutilizável.

Veja os [exemplos introdutórios](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/lambda/using_library.html#lambda.introductory_examples) para a biblioteca `Boost.Lambda`. Um deles resolve a expressividade com a técnica anterior, em troca de legibilidade e praticidade:

```
std::sort(begin(v), end(v), *_1 > *_2);
```

O que `*_1` e `*_2` significam não é óbvio pra ninguém: é preciso procurar na documentação de `Boost.Lambda` para entender todos os efeitos possíveis e o que pode ser feito com esses placeholders. Nesse caso, `*_1 > *_2` cria um objeto de função cujo predicado tem o mesmo propósito do de `std::greater`. Essa solução não escala bem com predicados mais elaborados e pode chegar a prejudicar o tempo de compilação, como também a qualidade do programa otimizado.

Todas essas alternativas falham em algum dos três pontos: legibilidade, expressividade e praticidade. Com isso em mente, funções lambdas foram introduzidas em [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) com o intuito de resolver esses três pontos. Lambdas são meramente objetos de função (ou seja, seu funcionamento é idêntico a como definimos structs para functors anteriormente). A [explicação do Maniero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/270901/39641) é suficiente e não preciso repeti-la aqui.

Vamos usar o primeiro exemplo com uma lambda:

```
auto it = std::find_if_not(std::begin(str), std::end(str), [](char c) {
    return (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') || (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z');
});
```

O predicado é visível logo no ponto de uso, o que favorece a legibilidade do código e a praticidade. Não existe nenhuma mágica na definição do predicado; podemos usar qualquer artifício da linguagem livremente no corpo da lambda, favorecendo a expressividade. Todos os três pontos estão resolvidos com essa solução. Vamos ver o outro exemplo:

```
std::sort(begin(v), end(v), [](int a, int b) { return a > b; });
```

Embora tenhamos mais código agora (comparando com `std::greater<>()` e `*_1 > *_2`), não precisamos mais depender de nenhuma biblioteca externa, nem procurar a definição de algum functor, ou mesmo entender como o functor é definido. É claro que, nesse exemplo em específico, usar `std::greater` é recomendado no lugar da lambda, uma vez que tal functor é padrão na linguagem.

Enfim, existe mais funcionalidades em lambdas (como a captura de variáveis, lambdas com closure/fecho mutável etc) que estão fora de escopo da pergunta.

Normalmente, otimizar uma lambda é mais fácil do que uma função, uma vez que não existe nenhum nome com ligação externa (pois a definição da lambda é anônima) e nenhum endereço de função é passado como argumento, apenas a instância da struct que define a lambda. Ou seja, é um valor que é útil ao sistema de tipos da linguagem e que o compilador pode gerar um código mínimo, que faz uso apenas do corpo da lambda.

Uma boa regra geral é utilizar lambdas sempre, a não ser que já exista um objeto de função definido pela standard (como no caso de `std::greater`.)

* Um functor, ou [function object](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional) (objeto de função), é um termo não oficial (sendo *function object* o termo oficial) usado por programadores em [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b). Uma de suas definições pode ser *um objeto para qual o operador de chamada de função é definido*.

Answer (score 3):

A *lambda* não tem um nome definido em tempo de compilação, ela é tratada como um valor.

Pensa que a função normal é como se fosse uma constante e o único jeito de chamá-la é usar o nome desta constante. Uma *lambda* é uma função que é um valor e precisa ser atribuída à uma variável, aí você chama a variável, assim estará executando a função.

Como ela é um valor pode ser atribuída para várias variáveis, em qualquer lugar do código, incluindo *arrays* e parâmetros.

Então dá uma enorme flexibilidade, você pode fazer algoritmos ou estruturas que tem uma base de como deve ser, mas alguma parte será definida depois em algum outro ponto do código, então a execução fica parametrizada.

Sabe [herança e polimorfismo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/154421/101)? Quando é permitido (sempre que seja virtual), uma classe derivada pode trocar o algoritmo da classe base (embora quase sempre o ideal é fazer algo extra e chamar o método da classe base).

O mesmo vale pra interface (que não existe em C++ ainda, só uma classe puramente abstrata, mas em C++20/23 poderá ter através de biblioteca, e sim, poderá criar sintaxe através da biblioteca). Você tem uma [assinatura de função/método](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/39870/101), mas não a implementação. A implementação vem na classe, depois.

A *lambda* permite algo mais flexível, cada objeto pode ter uma implementação diferente. Claro, precisa ter algum lugar no objeto que esteja esperando uma *lambda* com mesma assinatura.

De forma geral o preço pode ser o mesmo de um método virtual normal, ou seja, tem uma [indireção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181032/101) adicional, mas nada mais que isso. Dependendo da implementação pode ser um pouco melhor que o método virtual, embora eu ache que qualquer compilador decente otimize tanto que fica igual à *lambda*.

Uma *lambda* pode se tornar uma [*closure*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/34907/101), aí tem um custo adicional de memória e processamento por causa das variáveis capturadas.

E esta é outra vantagem da *lambda*, como ela pode ser transportada para vários lugares, as variáveis de escopo externo a ela passam fazer parte dela, como em uma função normal interna, porém a função normal não vai a lugar algum, então as variáveis externas são acessíveis nela, mas não precisam ser capturadas.

Não quero me estender muito nisto porque não é o foco da pergunta.

Sob certas circunstâncias é possível intercambiá-la com um [ponteiro para função](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/137773/101) ou [functor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/158994/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Conceptual.md).