# Atribuição e OO em Python

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos, variáveis

Estudando sobre orientação a objetos em Python me foi dito que uma diferença de tal linguagem na instancia e atribuição de uma classe é, ao fazermos

```
Darth = Pessoa ( 'Darth Vader' )
```

O nome / apelido `Darth` está sendo atribuído a classe e não o contrário, que acredito ser o comumente inferido pelos desenvolvedores já que *o contrário* é valido para outros itens como variáveis de tipos  primitivos da linguagem `int`, `float`, `bool`, `str`...

No material em vídeo que eu encontrei nada além disso foi dito (esse é o motivo de eu não deixar o mesmo como fonte nesta pergunta), sendo assim gostaria de saber se de fato isso ocorre, e se ocorre o que isso interfere no desenvolvimento e o que deveríamos saber sobre o tema para que não cometamos erros?

Como funciona atribuir ao objeto um apelido e não o objeto ao apelido?

Comment: Defina o contrário. Atribuir uma classe para um objeto? Isso é impossível. Já posso adiantar que o material parece ruim. Essas frases da pergunta não fazem muito sentido. `como funciona atribuir ao objeto um apelido e não o objeto ao apelido` Sobre o que está falando? O que é apelido para você?

Comment: O ' contrario ' : a ideia de que o objeto é atribuído a variável / nome / apelido / símbolo ... como preferir chamar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Fontes confiáveis

Primeiro começo dizendo que é comum vídeo aulas serem ruins, em geral são feitas por pessoas voluntariosas que nada entendem do assunto que não consegue se auto avaliar em um efeito [Dunning-Krugger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect) e ensinam errado. O problema é que a pessoa que não sabe ainda não consegue discernir o que é bom ou não. Claro que tem material ruim que não é vídeo e existem aulas boas assim, em geral pagas e curadas em algum lugar que precisa de credibilidade. Mesmo o que é bem recomendado pode ser ruim porque em geral as pessoas que recomendam não sabem avaliar se é bom, então consideram bom o que na verdade não é.

## Orientação a objetos

Precisa entender que orientação a objeto não é algo mágico que resolve problemas de programação por si só. É um [paradigma](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/141624/101) que ajuda certos problemas, não todos problemas. Não é uma linguagem de programação. É um paradigma secundário em todas as linguagens *mainstream*. As pessoas falam tanto nisto por modismo. As pessoas querem estar na moda, seguir a manada e por querem que seus códigos sejam OO, mesmo quando não precisa ou sequer é. É frequente vermos perguntas aqui com *tag* [orientação-a-objetos](/questions/tagged/orienta%c3%a7%c3%a3o-a-objetos) que não tem uma vírgula sequer sobre OOP. A pessoa só quer estar nesse grupo popular. E este é um dos motivos das pessoas quererem aprender OOP. Pena que elas não querem aprender onde usar o paradigma e onde não usar. Não querem aprender o que é o paradigma de fato.

É muito mais importante entender fundamentos gerais da computação do que OOP. Claro que em determinado momento precisa de OOP também, mas precisa aprender direito e não pode seguir receitas de bolo.

Eu até entendo que algumas pessoas acham que orientação a objeto é jogar com as palavras. Se for isso, ela serve pra nada. Tem que ter um efeito prático.

## Seu problema

A linha `Darth = Pessoa('Darth Vader')` está chamando um construtor da classe `Pessoa` passando como argumento um texto com um nome de uma pessoa e este objeto está sendo atribuído para uma [variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101). Bom, na verdade não sei se é um construtor. Python deixa a sintaxe ambígua e poderia ser só uma função normal, mas tudo indica que é construtor. Qualquer coisa que imagine além disso é especulação ou algo inexistente.

Ele gerará um objeto igualzinho ele faria com um `int`, `float`, `bool`, etc. Tudo isso é objeto também. Eles costumam ser objetos por valor, que algumas pessoas gostam de chamar de primitivos. Você cria instâncias desses tipos também. Mas em Python eles não são, em Python tudo está no *heap* e tudo é referência. Ainda assim eles possuem semântica de tipos de por valor.

Algumas pessoas chamam *string* de primitiva, o que não sei se é, depende do conceito do que é um primitivo. Se é algo que o computador consegue processar diretamente então não é primitivo. Se é algo que a linguagem dá um tratamento especial, então é possível, dependendo da linguagem.

## Composição de objetos

Em Python a única forma de criar um objeto composto por outros objetos dentro de um formato específico é com a classe. Também pode criar coleções de dados, mas isso serve a outro propósito, não vou entrar em detalhes aqui. Essas classes são sempre por referência, assim como são as coleções como listas e dicionários, por exemplo. Outros tipos são por referência, mas possuem semântica de valor, e isso é muito importante. Elas possuem identidade e são [imutáveis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15510/101).

Ao contrário do que muita gente pensa uma classe é apenas uma forma de estruturar, de planificar um objeto. Isso não é orientação a objeto. Está criando um modelo para um objeto, mas não orientado a ele. Uma linguagem não é conhecida por ser orientada a objeto, embora pode-se programar assim nela, com dificuldade, e você cria objetos nela da mesma forma.

Então o código apresentado na pergunta tem zero orientação a objeto. Se ensinaram assim, ensinaram errado.

Agora, a forma como a classe foi criada pode ser orientada a objeto. Precisa ver se o detalhe de implementação está encapsulado, se existe uma abstração, se o objeto pode ser constituído de outro objeto, se ele pode assumir a forma de outro objeto. Se seguir tudo isso corretamente é provável que deverá adotar certos padrões para realizar certas tarefas, prover certos mecanismo e alcançar certos objetivos. Se seguir uma parte talvez seja um [código modular](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/223549/101) que muitos acham que é orientado a objeto.

Como efeito do encapsulamento deve existir um construtor, isso começa ser um pouco orientado a objeto.

Mas o que está aí pouco importa se é OO ou não. É uma linha muito simples que não quer dizer muita coisa.

## Variáveis

Posso estar enganado, mas me pareceu que ainda não entende [o que é variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101), que é o básico do básico. Claro, muita gente que programa há anos também não sabe. O que me incomoda é a pessoa não saber pra que serve um tijolo e ela querer fazer arte na construção. Isso está errado. Antes de aprender uma técnica avançada de acabamento precisa fazer tudo se sustentar direito.

Não sei bem o que é um apelido aí. É a variável? Uma variável não pode ser atribuída para um objeto, em qualquer paradigma, isso não faz sentido. Pode ser que viu um jogo de palavras. Se o resultado é exatamente o mesmo, é tudo o mesmo. Pode ser que foi dito que em orientação a objeto dá-se um nome para um objeto e em outro paradigma coloca-se um objeto em um nome, que é exatamente o mesmo pra todos efeitos. Ou quase.

Variável é nome para um local de armazenamento de dados. Mas variável não é todo objeto que está na memória. Variável armazena dados básicos, em geral por valor ou pelo menos com essa semântica. Quando não armazena algo por valor ela só armazena a referência para outro objeto.

Por isso costuma-se dizer que **variáveis são caixas**. E são mesmo, é onde dados vão dentro dela. Mas entenda que a variável é o nome para o local do armazenamento. Ela não existe no concreto, existe apenas no seu código. Em toda variável há um dado, que pode ser a identidade do objeto (por valor) ou não (por referência). Em Python todo objeto é por referência, então toda variável é uma referência. Nunca terá o objeto propriamente dito nela.

Quando há uma referência há uma caixa que aponta para outra caixa que é o objeto que interessa. Esta outra caixa não é uma variável nunca, pelo menos em toda implementação que conheço. Em Python toda variável possui essas duas caixas e uma delas tem um nome que acho que é o que está chamando de apelido.

Não é possível sequer atribuir um objeto ao apelido, atribui-se um valor a uma variável, onde terá um local de armazenamento para a referência e outro para a identidade do objeto.

## Conclusão

Na outra pergunta fala:

> faz mais sentido dizer que a variável é atribuída a um objeto e não o contrário, ou seja, o objeto é criado antes da atribuição

Acontece que a variável é criada antes, ela já existe ali no código e na memória antes de existir o objeto, o objeto é criado e depois atribuído na variável que já existe. Então essa frase não faz sentido.

> A tentativa de multiplicação por uma instância de `Foo`, levanta uma exceção, mas o efeito colateral da saída do `id` de `Foo` prova que uma segunda instancia foi criada antes da tentativa de multiplicação.

Isso só prova que o tipo `Foo` não pode fazer uma multiplicação. Não faz sentido.

> Como as variáveis são apenas rótulos, nada impede que um objeto tenha vários rótulos atribuídos a ele

Variáveis, em Python, são sempre referências então elas sempre podem apontar para o mesmo objeto. só isso. Na tem a ver com rótulos. O rótulo é o nome, mas não o local de armazenamento.

Tem outras confusões ali. Eu até entendo qual era a intenção da resposta, mas a falta do fundamento acaba criando mais confusão.

Tem muita invenção sobre o assunto, o AP deve ter visto uma delas. Pode ser que tentaram simplificar o entendimento, o que é bom, mas o resultado foi que ensinaram errado.

Fora isso a pergunta é muito ampla, o que mais tem que saber sobre o tema é... tudo sobre o tema, não tem como pular partes, informação pela metade causa mais problema que ajuda.

Veja também, mesmo sendo outra linguagem: [Alocação de memória em C# - Tipos valor e tipos referência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14490/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Conceptual.md).

Comment: **pena que elas não querem aprender onde usar o paradigma e onde não usar**  - me fez lembrar da época da escola em que os alunos aprendem a resolver equações de segundo grau mas não sabem onde é a aplicabilidade delas e nem como aplica-las em problemas reais. Parece que as vezes só "aprendem" para passar nas provas. E isso parece acontecer muito em relação aos fundamentos da computação :/

Comment: @gato o que na escola muita coisa é assim mesmo, precisava de uma reformulação no ensino.

Comment: Sim, sei que aulas em vídeo não são a melhor forma, porém já li um pouco sobre Oo em dois livros e um ebook ( C ++ & Python ).

A questão de eu perguntar é que vejo o Python abstraindo muito e por conseguinte criando o que você mesmo disse : ' a moda mainstream ', onde apenas se usa e não se entende.

Comment: Estou começando a ter a base de que apenas usar classe ou itens relacionados ( A qualquer que seja o paradigma ) não faz da aplicação ' Orientada a Objetos ' ( Ou funciona, estrutural ... ), e com essa resposta você me ajudou a mensurar isso ( :

Comment: Acredito que devo ter feito confusão como você mesmo explicou na parte final de sua resposta.

Answer (score 2):

Quando vi a pergunta lembrei de um capítulo do excelente livro do Ramalho, [Python Fluente,](https://novatec.com.br/livros/pythonfluente/), quando retornei para escrever já havia a reposta do @Maniero, mas para complementar decidi postar minha resposta, baseado nas ideias do Ramalho.

> **Editado (23/07)**
>   Depois de uma análise mais apurada, percebi que, para ser justo, tenho que concordar 100% com o vídeo, embora, possa ter pecado, segundo o autor da pergunta, por não explicar em detalhes a afirmação que faz.

### Variáveis não são caixas

É bastante frequente, em aulas de programação, a metáfora de caixas para explicar o conceito de variável. Luciano Ramalho em seu livro "Fluent Python" afirma que essa metáfora, na verdade, atrapalha o entendimento de variáveis de referência em linguagens OO. As variáveis em python, são como variáveis de referencia em Java, então é melhor pensar nelas como rótulos associados a objetos.
Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = a
a.append(4)
b

[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Dessa forma faz mais sentido dizer que a variável é atribuida a um objeto e não o contrário, ou seja, o objeto é criado antes da atribuição.

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        print ('Foo id: %d' % id(self))

bar = Foo()       
Foo id: 140015331427608


y = Foo() * 10

Foo id: 140015331465200
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-a4f3c60ebf6e> in <module>()
----> 1 y = Foo() * 10

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'Foo' and 'int'
```

A tentativa de multiplicação por uma instancia de Foo, levanta uma exceção, mas o efeito colateral da saida do id de Foo prova que uma segunda instancia foi criada antes da tentativa de multiplicação.
Como as variáveis são apenas rótulos, nada impede que um objeto tenha vários rótulos atribuidos a ele. Quando isso acontece, temos os apelidos ou aliases.

```
joao = {'name': 'João J. Tompson', 'rg': '12345677-9' }
johny = joao
johny is joao
True

id(johny), id(joao)
(140015331669624, 140015331669624)
```

O operador is mostra que jonhy é uma apalido (alias) para joao.

Vamos alterar Joao atraves de johny

```
johny['cpf']='0988776699-00'
print (joao)
{'name': 'João J. Tompson', 'rg': '12345677-9', 'cpf': '0988776699-00'}
```

Agora sumponha que jonas alega ser joao, apenas pq tem as mesmas credenciais.

```
jonas = {'name': 'João J. Tompson', 'rg': '12345677-9', 'cpf': '0988776699-00' }
```

Se compararmos os valores dos dois objetos obteremos `True`

```
jonas==joao
True
```

Porem se comparamos os objetos (através do ID), veremos que não são os mesmos:

```
jonas is joao
False.
```

### [Da documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#objects-values-and-types)

Todo objeto tem uma identidade, um tipo e um valor, a identidadede um objeto não muda depois que ele é criado, voce pode pensar nela como o endereçõ na memoria, o operador is compara a identidade de dois objetos, a função id() devolve o interiro que representa a identidade do objeto.

Comment: Que bom que gostou da minha resposta, mas ela diz o oposto da sua. Eu lamento que algumas pessoas começaram ter esse entendimento de variáveis que elas não são. Lamento que a moda atual é aprender abstrações e não concretudes porque o concreto é o que funciona mesmo. Quando se pensa nessa forma, aprende algo falso. Variáveis são caixas, grossamente falando. Não são rótulos. Essa ideia é uma invenção que não tem fundamento. Na minha resposta tem um *link* que fala mais sobre variáveis.

Comment: Eu entendo que as pessoas confundam o objeto que a variável sustenta com seu valor, mas isso não faz ser uma verdade. Também tem um *link*  na minha resposta sobre tipos por valor e por referência. Eu entendo que algum livro queira usar uma metáfora para simplificar um explicação, mas ela engana o leitor a achar que é uma coisa quando é outra. Não vou em 3 comentários tentar explicar o funcionamento do mecanismo, mas está nos *links* apresentados. Esta resposta está tecnicamente correta, mas leva a um pensamento equivocado. Faça o mesmo com um inteiro e nada disso vale.

Comment: Como o mesmo mecanismo pode ter comportamentos diferentes? Porque ele não tem, o que explica o funcionamento do inteiro deveria ser a mesma explicação do funcionamento de um objeto criado por uma classe. Quando se conceitual a variável como caixas a mesma explicação funciona para o mesmo mecanismo. Só precisa entender que o mecanismo da variável por referência possui 2 caixas, uma na variáveis e outra no objeto. A primeira caixa é um endereço de onde está a segunda caixa.

Comment: É verdade, li sua resposta 'un passant' e achei bem interessante, mas depois lendo com cuidado, vi que, realmente, contradiz a minha (em alguns tópicos)  e, imo, vc esta equivocado, pelo menos em relação ao python. Procure por muttable x immutable objects in python, e entenda pq "Como o mesmo mecanismo pode ter comportamentos diferentes".

Comment: Isso não deveria ser diferente em uma linguagem, a não ser que Python esteja querendo ser PHP e inventar coisas. Na verdade eu nunca vi explicações em Python desta forma, até porque sei que o Guido tem conhecimento profundo de como as coisas funcionam. Salvo eu ter entendido algo errado acho que isso é criação paralela de quem gosta de inventar. Imutabilidade nada tem a ver com fato de variáveis serem caixas e não rótulos, e esse é o problema. Na computação variáveis serem foram lugares de armazenamento de dados, nunca um selinho. Só deveriam mudar isso se tivesse sentido, e com muito estudo.

Comment: Caramba meu.... não sei se seria interessante para o  STOpt ficarmos discutindo aqui nos comentários, mas talvez vc poderia entender um pouco melhor se lesse pelo menos os [capitulos 8 e 9 desse livro.](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920032519.do)

Comment: Mas é isto o que estou falando, esse livro está inventando coisas, pelo menos baseado no que você disse, eu não o li. tem conceitos consolidados há décadas que funcionam muito bem, não é necessário inventar coisa nova. Só porque está em um livro que acabou de ser publicado que seja uma coisa certa, muito menos boa. É uma forma de explicar, ok, quer quiser consumir isto pode fazer, mas não é necessário. O fato de se basear nesse livro mostra que isto é algo paralelo e não algo genuíno do Python. Talvez o livro nem venda muito essa ideia, mas se vende eu diria que é só pra ter uma "novidade".

Comment: O livro tem elogios de toda a comunidade python, inclusive por parte do Guido, será q isso conta para vc?

Comment: Tambem não mencionei na resposta, essa "estorinha" de que variáveis não são caixas, na verdade não é do autor do livro e sim de uma professora dele em um curso que ele fez no MIT.

Comment: Não conta porque eu sei como essas coisas funcionam, o Guido elogiará qualquer coisa que faça Python ser divulgado. E o livro deve ser bom, mas esse ponto citado é invenção desnecessária. Eu fico sempre com os fundamentos, mas acho que todo mundo pode seguir a invenção que quiser. Hoje a indústria tem marketing demais. Lamento que alguém do MIT pense assim porque não tem base, não é a ta que dizem que o nível das universidades americanas caiu muito. Quando se afasta dos fundamentos dá nisso. Mas já falei mais que devia, não cabe aqui, mas em minhas respostas tem esses fundamentos todos.

Comment: OK! Vc venceu. :-) Mas seria interessante considerar q pode estar equivocado. EOD.

Comment: Ok, décadas a computação está equivocada então, alguém descobriu que todo mundo esteve errado esse tempo todo, mas não tem um estudo confiável publicado e defendido pelos melhores engenheiros e cientistas da área, acho pouco provável, é muito mais provável isso ser invenção. Mas hoje em dia opiniões parecem valer mais que evidências, então não tem muito o que fazer. Por isso que eu não compro livros novos, o que tinha de útil já foi publicado há muito tempo, agora só copiam o que já existia ou inventam. Preferiria até a cópia com uma forma nova, mas não invenções.

Comment: Eu sempre considero que posso estar errado quando me oferecem evidências. Você poderia considerar isso também, sempre tem os lados. Eu me baseio em todos livros dos anos 60, 70, 80, 90 que eu li, e li muitos, os mais aclamados por todo mundo, não por uma comunidade. Mas novamente não estou dizendo que o livro é ruim, errado, o ponto não é esse.

Comment: Cara...vc não vê pq não quer, pelo menos em relação a python, vc esta **REDONDAMENTE** enganado, eu mostrei isso via codigo (primeiro o objeto é criado, depois a atribuição é feita) Um pouco de humildade lhe cairia bem.

Comment: Isso é conceito geral, não tem nada a ver com Python. Agora ficou claro que você não quer ver o que já está aí consolidado, se fixou em um livro. Pra falar a verdade nem sei se o problema é o livro porque já vi gente citando livro e aí eu fui ler, a pessoa não entendeu nada do que estava lá. O fato de você achar que isso tem a ver com Python indica que pode sr o caso. Eu conhece bem o funcionamento de linguagens e Pyhton funciona igual a todas linguagens nesse sentido, nem tem como ser diferente.

Comment: Na verdade eu acho que você problemas de interpretação de texto porque eu disse que sua resposta está correta, não questionei isso. O que você acaba de afirmar é o mesmo que eu disse. O problema é essa ideia de que variável é rótulo. O computador não funciona assim e tentar ver de outras forma é querer não entender o conceito correto. Mas é um direito seu fazer isso, nunca disse que não era. Tudo o que diz sobre ficar aberto a estar enganado, ter humildade, cabe para você também, principalmente porque você está se baseando em um trecho de um livro e eu em todo fundamento da computação

Comment: Como você começou ficar agressivo e agora só quer me criticar ao em vez de argumentar não vale mais a pen continuar. Esse tipo de coisa não leva a lugar algum e realmente isto não cabe aqui, debate de ideia é uma coisa diferente. Pelo menos as pessoas podem ler e tirar suas conclusões. E u não me importo em quem quiser acreditar em conto da carochinha, mas quem quer saber como as coisas realmente funcionam está aí toda informação. Mais pode ser lido em outras respostas minhas sobre o assunto.

Comment: @Sidon na verdade pensar numa variável como se fosse um balde ou uma caixa não atrapalha em nada o entendimento de variáveis de referencia, nada impede que dentro de uma caixa possa conter o endereço de outra caixa no qual esta outra coisa contenha um valor literal.

Comment: @gato  Ok, para mim a discussão está encerrada, acredito que prolonga-la não vai agregar nada. Acabamos caindo naquela 'pecha', "essa discussao esta baseada em opiniões... e blah blah blah"

Comment: @Sidon eu acho que você levou para o lado pessoal

Comment: @Sidon entenda que estamos aqui para ajudar as pessoas simplesmente porque queremos, as vezes é bom manter a calma e ser aberto a sugestões e criticas. E algumas criticas sempre acaba nos salvando ;)

Comment: @gato Putz.... Nada a ver, lado pessoal? Só acho inutil ficarmos nessa discussao aqui. Simplesmente isso. Só quero encerrar, tem um chat técnico? Me convide.

Comment: ' Segundo o autor da pergunta, por não explicar em detalhes a afirmação que faz ' - Tu pensou em não responder a minha pergunta formulada como um pedaço de lixo ?!  ^ - ^ ( Obs : >>>> ?! <<<<  )