# O que é projeto orientado a dados?

Tags: terminologia, desempenho, modelagem, estilo-de-codificação, paradigma-de-programação

Me deparei com o termo *data-oriented design*, vi algumas coisas e me surpreendi um pouco porque o que pude ver por cima é diferente do que eu poderia imaginar, já que esses termos normalmente remetem à maneiras de estruturar projetos de forma convoluta e prolixa para atender algum "requisito mágico" que nada tem a ver com o negócio. Eu achei até que já tinha visto isso, mas não era o que eu imaginava.

Na verdade o que eu estava pensando é *data-driven design*. Essas coisas que terminam com DD em geral pregam formas de projetos cheio de regras para alcançar algum objetivo onde não existem métricas que indicam sucesso. Esse chega ser até complicado chamar de DDD porque já tem outro DDD (já está faltando letras).

Então o que é o projeto orientado a dados?

Por que devemos adotá-lo e em que casos?

Qual a relação que ele tem com orientação a objetos?

Por ser dados é algo a ser usado em banco de dados? Pode ser usado em outro contexto?

Tem como comprovar sua eficácia? (métricas)

Pode dar um exemplo bem curtinho de código onde é diferente?

É um paradigma? (Coloquei a *tag* por não ter certeza)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Qual a relação que ele tem com orientação a objetos?

De fato é fácil confundir com o [projeto dirigido a dados](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data-driven_programming) que é algo ligado à orientação a objeto, ao contrário do projeto **orientado** a dados em questão aqui, que **se opõe à OO**.

> É um paradigma?

Na verdade é um estilo ou abordagem de programação, pelo menos oficialmente não é um [paradigma](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/141624/101), se fosse seria bem secundário.

> Então o que é o projeto orientado a dados?

Ele procura organizar os dados da forma que melhor faz sentido para a aplicação aproveitar melhor o hardware, independente do código ficar mais organizado ou não.

Ele é oposto de outros estilos que procuram uma forma de escrever "melhor" os códigos, ele realmente coloca o dado em primeiro lugar poder manipulá-lo eficientemente é prioridade, mesmo que eventualmente o código fique estranho.

O seu objetivo é organizar os campos em estruturas de dados para melhor [aproveitar a memória](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_access_pattern), o [cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache), o transporte e o processamento. Em geral ele diminui a ociosidade da máquina evitando o [Von Neumann bottlenecking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_architecture#Von_Neumann_bottleneck) que impede o processador de exercer o seu potencial por causa da forma que os dados que estão estruturados.

> Por que devemos adotá-lo e em que casos?

Então é claro que é mais útil em aplicações que exigem o máximo de desempenho, e jogos é um exemplo frequentemente citado como DOD.

> Por ser dados é algo a ser usado em banco de dados? Pode ser usado em outro contexto?

Também é adotado em bancos de dados onde a organização dos dados ajuda no desempenho das consultas. Muitas vezes modelamos usando o [*data-oriented design*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data-oriented_design) sem nem percebermos, pelo menos em bancos de dados relacionais.

De fato as aplicações que usam esta abordagem costumam privilegiar um conjunto de listas ou tabelas de dados simples ([SoA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AOS_and_SOA#Structure_of_arrays)) do que listas de objetos completos (AoS), assim os dados relacionados ficam juntos e o acesso é otimizado.

A normalização de banco de dados costuma fazer um pouco isto em alguns casos.

> Tem como comprovar sua eficácia?

Existem métricas fáceis já que estamos falando de desempenho. É possível medir usando os dois modelos, OOP e DOD, o segundo ninguém pode questionar que houve ganho, tem números claros e incontestáveis. Se o ganho é necessário é outra estória. O ganho em fazer OOP sempre pode ser questionado, nunca conseguiram publicar um estudo conclusivo do ganho.

> Pode dar um exemplo bem curtinho de código onde é diferente?

No SO tem exemplos de como é em OOP:

```
class Ball {
    Point  position;
    Color  color;
    double radius;
    void draw();
};

vector<Ball> balls;
```

E como é em DOD:

```
class Balls {
    vector<Point>  position;
    vector<Color>  color;
    vector<double> radius;
    void draw();
};
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Vector/DOD.cpp).

#Mais informações

Mike Acton é o principal proponente e descobri o assunto como algo mais ou menos formalizado em [palestra dele](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rX0ItVEVjHc).

[Existem textos que detonam OOP](http://gamesfromwithin.com/data-oriented-design) ([outro](http://www.dataorienteddesign.com/dodmain/node17.html)). Claro que no contexto específico, mas é bom pra abrir o olho do que pode estar te prejudicando, mesmo que não precise.

Ele mostra como é prejudicial um simples polimorfismo que parece inofensivo, já que é apenas uma [indireção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181032/101) simples de ponteiro, mas que prejudica a localidade e chega causar uma lentidão de mais de uma ordem de magnitude, o que é um absurdo, só porque [a informação não está no cache](http://www.dice.se/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/Introduction_to_Data-Oriented_Design.pdf). Ele chega propor, na medida do possível que o polimorfismo seja gerado dentro das funções e não dentro dos objetos, ou que tudo seja resolvido em tempo de compilação.

O estilo abomina o uso de exceções, herança múltipla, abstrações, entre outras técnicas típicas de aplicações *enterprise*.

Obviamente que isto se aplica melhor em C++. Outras linguagens praticamente tornam o DOD inútil porque elas já possuem seus próprios gargalos. C ou Assembly estão em um nível inferior de abstração.

Há um [site com praticamente um livro sobre o assunto](http://www.dataorienteddesign.com/dodmain/dodmain.html).

[Palestra do Scott Myers sobre cache](https://vimeo.com/97337258).

Muita gente deve ter se decepcionado porque queriam ver aquelas arquiteturas cheias de padrões que tornam o código enorme e confuso para atingir um objetivo que muitas vezes nem é necessário.