# Aplicação de algoritmos em POO

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, algoritmo

O algoritmo/lógica de programação é voltada para programação estruturada. Como seria a aplicar algoritmo em POO?

Comment: Você pergunta como seria, por exemplo, lógica de programação orientada a objetos?

Comment: Não mudaria tanta coisa, claro dependendo da implementação desejada. 
 Recomendo que procure estudar estrutura de dados em linguagens orientadas a objetos, tal como Java. Quando estava estudando estruturas eu estudei por linguagem orientada a objetos e apliquei em C que é estrutural.

Comment: Sim, isso ae, pois quando, pois é muito dinâmico a POO.

Comment: Você tem algoritmo funcional, algoritmo estruturado, algoritmo orientado a existência de funções que residem a entidades, algoritmo orientado a objetos propriamente dito, algoritmo de "linguagem de montagem", algoritmo em Máquinas de Turing, em gramáticas irrestritas... Algoritmo é uma sequência de regras finitas para se fazer uma computação/um cálculo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Programação orientada a objeto nada tem a ver com algoritmo, tem a ver com estrutura de dados.

Claro que a forma como estrutura os dados afeta em como fará o algoritmo, mas é mais pela organização do que por ele em si. Por exemplo, reduz-se o uso de desvios condicionais e adota-se decisões baseadas em qual objeto foi instanciado. Muda a forma como os algoritmos internos e externos vão se comunicar. Muda a forma de codificar certas atividades por causa dos compromissos assumidos por um objeto neste paradigma.

[Há controvérsias até se OO é um paradigma](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/141624/101). Até é, mas secundário. Sem outro paradigma, não existe OOP.

Por isso essa obsessão que as pessoas tem por fazer tudo OOP não faz sentido. A obsessão é tão grande que a maioria sequer se dá ao trabalho de aprender o paradigma para aplicar na forma correta onde precisa. Ela só quer dizer que fez OOP porque dizem que fazendo assim tudo é melhor, o que também é outra mentira. Tem cenário que não fica bom com OO e se fizer OO errado certamente ficará ruim, provavelmente pior que sem OO.