# Modelagem de sistemas precisa de Java?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, modelagem

Usei diagramas de dados estruturados há mais de 15 anos atrás. Em 2002 Não usei POO. Quero reaprender modelagem de sistemas usando POO. Indicam algum material? 
Preciso aprender Java ou apenas POO em UML sem linguagem de programação Java?

Comment: Só modelar? Não seria o caso de estudar UML?

Comment: POO, é um paradigma de programação, um padrão de desenvolvimento que pode ser utilizado em muitas linguagens de programação, como C# e JAVA. Você pode aprender a modelar projetos de software seguindo o padrão POO e então decidir qual tecnologia ou conjunto de tecnologias irá utilizar. Abaixo segue alguns link que considero útil, pelo que entendi da sua dúvida: http://protocoloti.blogspot.com.br/2012/04/paradigmas-de-programacao.html https://www.devmedia.com.br/usando-tecnicas-de-orientacao-a-objetos-para-modelar-e-implementar-objetos-de-negocio/5928 https://www.devmedia.com.br/conheca-os-padro

Comment: Existia OOP sim, eu uso há 30 anos, tem quem usa há mais de 40. O fato de não conhecer algo não quer dizer que não existe. Alias esse é um dos maiores problemas no aprendizado de hoje em dia. As pessoas não são capazes de avaliar se o que estão aprendendo é bom ou não, e isso é normal, o problema é que tem sempre gente "vendendo" informação errada e como as pessoas têm preguiça de procurar avaliação adequada aprendem tudo errado. Achar informação é fácil, achar o que é bom é bem mais complicado. Quase toda informação sobre OOP disponível está errada e as pessoas proliferam esses erros.

Comment: Você precisa aprender tudo, se souber só uma parte é quase o mesmo que não saber nada. Na verdade é pior porque saber uma parte e achar que sabe tudo dá uma confiança equivocada que trará prejuízos. OO é bem mais complicado do que parece porque o grosso do que precisa aprender não está em livro algum, menos ainda em blogs. Na verdade é necessário aprender taxinomia e ontologia. OOP e Java são coisas completamente ortogonais. OOP é só uma forma de organizar, ela não faz milagre. E a maioria abusa e faz sistemas horríveis só pra seguir a receita.

Comment: Sobre paradigmas tem aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/141624/101 Na verdade a maioria das informações que desejar já tem postado aqui no site.

Comment: Você quis dizer que há 15 anos atrás (2003) não havia POO ou que você não a usava? Eu usava POO em 2003.

Comment: Exato, @Victor-Stafusa Eu **não usava POO**, por isso fiz linguagem estruturada no **curso de TPD** (que não existe mais e não me formei, faltando só o **TCC**). Por isso, estou retornando **sem ling. estruturada**. Como disse **Maniero** , vou focar primeiro na POO. A disciplina é para o próximo semestre, daí minha antecipação ao conhecimento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modelagem de sistemas **NÃO** precisa de Java, bem... Não precisa de nenhuma linguagem de programação!

O que quer se dizer ao usar "vamos modelar o sistema" é "vamos fazer um esboço inicial do projeto". Modelar seria, fazendo uma comparação com engenharia, fazer uma "maquete" da obra; não é executar a obra em si, mas montar um cenário onde ela estaria completa, mostrando como ela afetaria a área em volta.

Modelagem de sistemas, principalmente usando UML, é **geralmente voltada para o paradigma orientado à objetos**, mas pode ser usada com outros paradigmas.

A linguagem de modelagem mais comum a ser utilizada é, se não me engano, a UML. Ela tem, nas versões mais recentes, 14 tipos de diagramas para serem usados de forma a detalhar o programa desde como as atividades no programa seguem até mapear o relacionamento de classes, de estados do objeto até como o projeto deve ser implantado.

Você pode achar vários programas que tanto fazem diagramas UML como até mesmo convertem eles em código. Um deles é o [Visual Paradigm](https://www.visual-paradigm.com/features/code-engineering-tools/), que faz os diagramas gratuitamente, mas a conversão em código pelo próprio programa necessita de versão paga. Outro é o [Umbrello](https://umbrello.kde.org/), apenas para Linux, que faz tanto os diagramas como geração de código.

Sobre a linguagem de modelagem em si, você pode encontrar mais coisas no [site da UML](http://www.uml.org/index.htm).

Comment: Grato, @mutlei Revi conceitos que tinha procurando melhorar mais a cada leitura como essa do seu comentário. Por exemplo, POO já existia sim há 15 anos atrás e acredito que o uso de Java será necessário na fase que citou: **até mapear o relacionamento de classes, de estados do objeto até como o projeto deve ser implantado** 
Como apresentei antes a dúvida, por estar desatualizado no assunto, estou em dúvida: em qual fase precisarei codificar ou usar Java. O que precisa ser mapeado e/ou transformado em linguagem Java? 
A ferramenta para diagramar o projeto em UML será Astah. Outra ideia a+?

Comment: Não é necessário usar Java. Isso serve pra qualquer linguagem com orientação a objetos; inclusive, Java não tem um dos recursos presentes no paradigma, a herança múltipla. Cada classe só pode herdar de uma classe somente, no Java, já em C++ a herança multipla é permitida. Bem-vindo ao mundo OO. :)