# É prudente utilizar vários paradigmas em um projeto C++?

Tags: c++, orientação-a-objetos, estilo-de-codificação, programação-funcional, paradigma-de-programação

Seria vantajoso utilizar vários paradigmas em um projeto no C++? Por exemplo, em determinada parte do código eu uso *reactive programming*, em outras partes eu utilizo OOP, e em outra eu utilizo programação funcional. Enfim, existe algum problema em fazer isso? Eu poderia me deparar com eventuais problemas no código futuramente?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sabendo o que está fazendo sempre é, não sabendo, usar um só já é muito :) E as pessoas usam o tempo todo vários deles. É comum algumas equipes proibirem certos padrões e em parte paradigmas na sua base de código, especialmente em C++ as pessoas tendem a trabalhar com um *subset* da linguagem.

Entenda que quase o tempo todo você estará programando imperativamente, querendo ou não. Hoje C++ tem uma capacidade maior de ser um pouco funcional, e muitos estão optando por esta forma também, mas é só auxiliar, ela nem consegue ser totalmente funcional, uma linguagem não pode ter esses dois paradigmas por completo ao mesmo tempo.

Ela tem vários outros [paradigmas secundários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/141624/101), e hoje a meta programação não só parece ser a mais forte, como é a tendência. A orientação a objeto também é usada, mas há quem pregue que seu uso seja evitado. Estão colocando contratos, eventos e programação reativa, só para citar alguns dos secundários.

O problema não é usar junto, é usar sem entender o que está fazendo, aí tudo pode dar errado futuramente.

Comment: Apenas para corroborar com a mistura de paradigmas, onde trabalho codificamos em Java e migramos praticamente todas as nossas iterações de coleções para um modelo mais funcional. Isso permitiu ver alguns pontos importantes de otimização que não víamos no modelo imperativo e permitiu muita limpeza devido a OO-zismos mal-feitos e extrapolados (além de que, esteticamente, ficou mais bonito de se ler e mais prazeroso de se escrever). Também serviu para corrigir pontos de falha no código que passaram despercebidos, como operações em objetos imutáveis sem guardar o retorno.

Comment: Mas mantivemos o grosso no modelo imperativo e onde calhava mantivemos uma "pegada mais OO"

Comment: "OO-zismos mal-feitos e extrapolados" é o que mais tem nos códigos por aí.