# Linguagens com apenas um paradigma têm alguma vantagem?

Tags: característica-linguagem, independente-de-linguagem, paradigma-de-programação

As linguagens de programação que possuem apenas um paradigma como [Haskell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskell_(programming_language)) (programação funcional) ou [Smalltalk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smalltalk) (orientada a objeto / orientado a mensagem) se beneficiam por concentrar o foco totalmente nesse paradigma?

- Quais são as perdas/ganhos de uma linguagem de programação possuir mais de um paradigma?
- Isso é bom ou ruim para nós que estamos desenvolvendo um software? (isso é bem pessoal de cada um, então vai ser baseada na experiência de vocês)

Referência: [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_paradigm#Overview)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ter apenas um paradigma dá uma vantagem sensacional, a linguagem é simples. mas tem uma desvantagem, ela fica simples demais para maioria dos problemas, portanto simplória.

Porém tem um problema em tudo isto. Algumas pessoas, eu entre elas, consideram que só existem 4 paradigmas. Eu já falei disto em [O que é paradigma?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/141624/101). De forma geral um impede o outro, então temos que considerar que a linguagem só pode ter um paradigma, nunca dois (é possível ter mais que um na mesma linguagem desde que não use um deles ao mesmo que outro, o que faria pouco sentido ter essa capacidade). Podem existir alguns paradigmas secundários que influenciam a linguagem, até mesmo um dos principais podem inspirar a linguagem em algum estilo, sem impor como paradigma. Esses estilos secundários, que geralmente não podem ser usados sozinhos, e principalmente o que é orientação não pode ser colocado no mesmo patamar.

A maioria dos paradigmas secundários dizem respeito a apenas uma parte do código e que muitas vezes nem é usado em alguma solução específica, portanto opcional.

Mesmo Smalltalk gera controvérsias se ela tem só a orientação a objeto. E de fato o próprio criador já admite que ele fez outra coisa ali e não é bem orientação a objeto, e também admite que tem linguagens que nunca foram consideradas orientadas a objeto e são mais orientadas a objeto que Smalltalk (Lisp e Erlang).

As linguagens citadas na pergunta obtiveram sucesso? Acho que isto explica muita coisa, certo? O criador de Haskell diz que ele criou uma linguagem que não serve pra nada prático. Não estou falando da qualidade delas. Você acha que as pessoas deixariam de usar algo claramente bom para tudo o que precisam?

Ter mais de um paradigma, se podemos dizer assim, ajuda a linguagem ser mais expressiva para problemas diferentes, e claro que a torna mais complexa.

Essa complexidade é geral: na especificação, na implementação, na documentação, no uso.

Tudo é bom ou ruim de acordo com o ponto de vista. Se fosse só ruim não existiria, se fosse só bom só existiria assim.

Nem pode dizer que C tenha só um paradigma mas é a única linguagem que conheço que é simples e não ficou em um nicho muito pequeno. Alguns dirão que até ficou sim, aí depende do que cada um enxerga o tamanho desse pequeno, isso é bem subjetivo. E C conseguiu o sucesso que teve por falta de algo melhor na época e porque seu mérito é ser o Assembly portável da computação, não por ser de apenas um paradigma.

Esta página da Wikipedia é uma das piores que eu já vi sobre desenvolvimento de software. Quem fez isso não partiu de um estudo. Faltam paradigmas, alguns não são ou nem fazem sentido. Existe uma hierarquia que eu não sei de onde saiu e o quanto está correta. Mas se considerar aquilo já fica impossível uma linguagem ter um só paradigma.

Lembrando que podemos adotar um paradigma secundário em linguagens que não o suportam diretamente com maior ou menor facilidade. Paradigma tem mais a ver como você escreve o código do que com a linguagem que pode ter alguma que facilite ou incentive esse estilo, que é algo especialmente válido quando se fala dos paradigmas secundários. Em geral só podemos falar que uma linguagem adota certo paradigma secundário por algum *syntax sugar* que ele fornece.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).