# Como aplicar esta classe de Login no meu formulário de Login?

Tags: php, mysql

```
     <?php 
        if (!empty($_POST)) {
            // Recebendo dados do Formulário
            $usuario = $Modulo->NoSqlInject((isset($_POST['usuario'])) ? $_POST['usuario'] : NULL);
            $senha   = $Modulo->NoSqlInject((isset($_POST['senha'])) ? $_POST['senha'] : NULL);
            // Iniciando o processo de conexão 
            $Usuario->LogarUsuario($usuario, $senha, '/index.php');
        }
    ?>
    <div class="login-box-body">
        <p class="login-box-msg">Faça login para iniciar sua sessão!</p>
        <form method="POST">
            <div class="input-group has-feedback">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="usuario" placeholder="Digite o nome de usuário" required>
            </div>

            <div class="input-group has-feedback" style="margin-top: 3%;">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="senha" placeholder="Digite a senha do usuário" required>
            </div>

            <div class="row" style="margin-top: 3%;">
                <div class="col-xs-8">
                    <div class="checkbox icheck">
                        <label><input type="checkbox" name="rememberme" value="rememberme"> Lembrar-me</label>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat" value="Acessar"></input>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

acima está o meu formulário, porém até ai tudo bem, funciona normal.

O `$Usuario->LogarUsuario($usuario, $senha, '/index.php');` ele faz o seu processo de verificação e cria as `$_SESSION` normal, mas é aqui que necessito de ajuda, quero colocar essas `$_SESSION` para funcionar do lado de fora, segue abaixo minha Usuario.class.php

[Usuario.class.php](https://pastebin.com/D0RYDSeU)
Bem, se houver algum erro me ajudem, e preciso por o "Lembrar minha Senha" também do lado de fora, está tudo ai o script.

Comment: Como assim fora? Para acessar as variáveis de sessão  é  preciso sempre iniciar uma session_start(); pelo que eu vi no seu código apenas o método logar usuário  inicia a sessão. Depois que a página é recarregada é preciso que o script recorrente tenha iniciado uma sessao tambem. Porém mesmo assim não consigo entender onde você quer usar as variáveis onde em que script?

Comment: Pronto Atila Silva, coloquei um session_start(); do lado de fora da .class, é que eu quero fazer o script assim: if($_SESSION['usuario_logado'] == TRUE) { echo 'SUCESSO!'; } else { echo 'FALHOU'; } ou seja == FALSE, sacou? só que isso eu tenho que colocar fora da .class.php no meu arquivo HTML! É isso que eu não estou conseguindo, eu consigo criar a sessão ao logar, menos fazer ela rodar do lado de fora da class!

Comment: DEIXA, já conseguir man! https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/286406/como-rodar-um-update-constante-no-session se puder me ajudar com isso, grato!

Comment: Bem. A orientação a objetos pode resolver o problema. Não sou tão bom leitor de código. Porém é sempre bom lembrar que a orientação a objetos caminha para diminuir o uso repetitivo de código. Bem você poderia seguir os as recomendações assim seu código se torna mais fácil de entender e de implementar. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/55508/74982