# POO é igual em todas as linguagens?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, característica-linguagem

O modo de estruturar, programando em POO é igual em todas as linguagens? Por exemplo, classe, interface, etc...

Comment: Não, se assemelha porém não é igual.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

## Linguagem orientada a objeto

Conforme [já respondido ao AP em pergunta anterior](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/211768/101), orientação a objeto não é exatamente um mecanismo de linguagem. O paradigma pode ser aplicado à qualquer linguagem, mesmo [aquelas que as pessoas não consideram ser orientadas a objeto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80228/101).

Já acho ruim esse negócio de dizer que a linguagem é orientada a objeto. Pior ainda é dizer que ela é totalmente orientada a objeto, o que não existe na prática, nem Smalltalk é (que aliás é absurdamente diferente de tudo o que costumamos usar, e segundo o seu criador, o termo orientado a objeto foi cunhado por ele, e portanto só essa linguagem ou as que sejam parecidas com ela são realmente OO, mas o conceito *mainstream* é a OO adotada pelo C++).

Já havia mostrado que [OOP é um paradigma secundário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/141624/101) e não pode existir por si só.

Algumas linguagens usam mecanismos específicos para ajudar atender os preceitos do paradigma. O mais comum é ter mecanismo de classes, interfaces, etc. Outras possuem [mecanismo de protótipos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15239/101). Algumas linguagens no fundo são protótipos travestidos de classes, muito comum em linguagens dinâmicas, como PHP. Nada impede de existir outro mecanismo totalmente diferente.

Na verdade [há controvérsias sobre o que é OOP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/88546/101). Inclusive algumas pessoas falam em OOP quando na verdade estão falando de OOD (*design* orientado a objeto) que são coisas parecidas mas não são a mesma coisa, porém isso é outro assunto. Há quem nem concorde quais são os mecanismos necessários para que a linguagem seja considerada, pelo menos parcialmente, como orientada a objeto.

## Mecanismos

Cada mecanismo específico pode ser implementado de formas diferentes. Existem [vários tipos de polimorfismo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/89309/101), e a linguagem pode implementar todos ou nenhum. Sim, ainda [dá para fazer polimorfismo sem que a linguagem facilite](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/53108/101), desde que ela seja [*Turing Complete*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/102452/101) e toda linguagem de programação deve ser. O polimorfismo genérico inclusive torna a linguagem participante de outro paradigma. O mesmo vale para outros mecanismos. Que eu saiba o único mecanismo exclusivo de OOP, até a data de hoje, é a herança.

Tem linguagem que não tem [interface](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2913/101), ou tem de um jeito diferente, tem linguagem que tem [trait](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73449/101), tem linguagem que implementa esse e outros mecanismos de forma errada, tem linguagem que diz ter um mecanismo, mas na verdade não tem. Tem linguagem que sequer tem uma sintaxe específica que ajude fazer OOP, conforme já dito antes.

Os mecanismos existem para dar mais comodidade, performance e outros ganhos secundários.

[JS não sabia o que é classe, hoje sabe](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/108548/101). Ela usa os dois mecanismos, ainda que um seja mais concreto e outro é apenas *syntax sugar*. Alguns dirão que tudo é *syntax sugar*, o que eu discordo. Tudo é abstração, que é um conceito diferente.

Todas características da linguagem vão interagir com as características específicas de OOP e vão fazer mudanças na sua implementação. Por exemplo, é diferente fazer OOP em linguagem de [tipagem dinâmica ou estática, tipagem estrutural ou nominal, e assim por diante](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/190463/101).

## Sintaxe

Nos comentários fala-se da sintaxe. Tenho minhas dúvidas se isso é relevante, mas certamente a sintaxe é diferente, seria quase impossível ela ser igual. Até mesmo em linguagens irmãs a sintaxe pode ser parecida, mas é diferente. Se for a mesma, é a mesma linguagem. Eu acho que na verdade queria saber sobre a semântica, e costuma ser diferente também, até pode tudo o que escrevi acima.

## Conclusão

Reforço o que o Renan falou, não podemos mais achar que a Terra é plana ou vacina causa autismo. Estamos na era da informação, onde tudo é muito fácil de ser aprendido, mas também é muito fácil desaprender. Nunca tivemos tantos casos da informação ser consumida rápida e superficialmente dando margem para aprender tudo errado e ficar na mão de quem mais facilmente manipula a realidade percebida.

Eu digo e repito que a maioria das pessoas acham que estão programando orientado a objeto quando não estão. As pessoas acham que criar uma classe é OOP, e não é. Na verdade a maioria dos códigos escritos OO seriam melhores escritos de outra forma, até pela incapacidade do programador de entender o que é OO.

#### Design X programação

Eu tenho uma teoria que OO foi criado para separar a função do engenheiro do codificador. A maioria dos desenvolvedores são apenas codificadores. Eu acho que faz sentido nesse caso. O engenheiro é um sujeito muito capacitado para fazer um bom *design* da aplicação e delega para o codificador a criação dos algoritmos e detalhes de implementação.

É claro que o profissional pode e frequentemente faz ambos, e pode ter vantagem fazer OO mesmo nesses casos, o que fica trágico é quando apenas mal sabe codificar e tentar ser engenheiro.

Leia mais:

- [O que é "Orientado a objeto" e quais outros métodos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/108047/101)
- [JavaScript é uma linguagem Orientada a Objetos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/141645/101)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: `Por isso discordo levemente do Renan quando diz que JS não sabe o que é classe. Ela usa os dois mecanismos, ainda que um seja mais concreto e outro é apenas syntax sugar.` Eu tava inflamado quando escrevi aquilo, foi mal XD

Comment: @Renan imaginei mesmo, depois eu edito a minha tb :) Compreendo muito isso, vive acontecendo comigo :)

Answer (score 15):

Não.

Muita gente aprende na faculdade ou nos tutoriais da Internet que C# e Java são orientadas a objeto por terem os conceitos de classe. E fica por isso mesmo. E é por causa dessa aceitação geral de informação vomitada que nós temos gente que acredita também que a Terra é plana e que vacinas causam autismo.

[<strike>Javascript não sabe o que é uma classe, mas é orientada a objetos</strike> Javascript permite programação OO sem necessariamente fazer uso de abstração por classes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/141645/javascript-%C3%A9-uma-linguagem-orientada-a-objetos/). Existem ainda outras linguagens ainda que não possuem o conceito de prototipagem e herança sem tipagem do Javascript, mas também são orientadas a objeto.

Então não, orientação a objetos não é igual em todas as linguagens. Ao invés de se perguntar isso, mais legal seria se perguntar [o que afinal de contas é a orientação a objeto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11098/qual-a-defini%C3%A7%C3%A3o-do-termo-acoplamento) e [por que ela surgiu](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/54310/origem-da-orienta%C3%A7%C3%A3o-a-objetos).

Answer (score 14):

> **tl;dr** matematicamente sim; na prática, um ou outro paradigma torna algumas construções sem sentido

Orientação a objetos é um ramo matemático de tratar entidades matemáticas que tenham atributos e comportamentos. Esse conceito, depois de muito bem estabelecido na matemática, foi absorvido nas linguagens de programação. Nesse sentido, a orientação a objetos é a mesma em todas as linguagens.

Em compensação, há alternativas de como se é feito isso. Existem linguagens não tipadas, linguagens com tipagem dinâmica e linguagens com tipagem de pato. Linguagens com tipagem de pato, por exemplo, podem dispensar o uso de interfaces. Leve em consideração também que a tipagem estática ajuda o programador a perceber que há um erro em seu código no momento da compilação (análise estática do código).

Também há diferenças de implementação que são bem relevantes. Em C++, para se usar o polimorfismo, é necessário declarar que o método é `virtual`, já em Java todo método não privado é considerado `virtual`.

Eu falo mais sobre interfaces e objetos [nessa outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/205559/64969), com direito a um foco especial ao Java no final da resposta. Focando aqui no primeiro item da lista da resposta acima linkada:

> interfaces são promessas de comportamento

Em linguagens com tipagem de pato, se eu tenho um objeto com acesso a método `pop`, `peek` e `push` então eu tenho um comportamento de `deque`; não preciso dizer isso para esse objeto, ele simplesmente tem esse comportamento, não preciso dizer que ele promete isso a priori.

Em algumas linguagens eu posso dinamicamente atribuir no os métodos a objetos já existentes, fazendo assim com que um objeto passe a cumprir uma promessa de comportamento em *run time*. Essa inserção dinâmica de métodos é normalmente associado com tipagem de pato.